# How do I access 'this' from within a C# extension method?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, this

I've been working with Vector2's and XNA, and I've come to find that calling the Normalize() member function on a Zero Vector normalizes it to a vector of {NaN, NaN}.  This is all well and good, but in my case I'd prefer it instead just leave them as Zero Vectors.

Adding this code to my project enabled a cute extension method:

```
using ExtensionMethods;

namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static Vector2 NormalizeOrZero(this Vector2 v2)
        {
            if (v2 != Vector2.Zero)
                v2.Normalize();
            return v2;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this method *returns* the normalized vector, rather than simply normalizing the vector which I use to invoke this extension method. I'd like to to instead behave as *vector2Instance*.Normalize() does.

Aside from making this void, how do I adjust this so that the 'v2' is modified?
(Essentially, I need access to the 'this' object, or I need 'v2' to be passed by reference.)

Edit:

And yes, I have tried this:

```
    public static void NormalizeOrZero(this Vector2 v2)
    {
        if (v2 != Vector2.Zero)
            v2.Normalize();
    }
```

Doesn't work, v2 is just a variable in the scope of NormalizeOrZero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because Vector 2 [is actually a struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.aspx).  This means it gets passed by value and you can't modify the caller's copy.  I think the best you can do is the workaround specified by lomaxxx.

This illustrates why you should generally avoid using structures.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class) for more information.  Vector2 violates the guideline that structs should be immutable, but it probably made sense to do so in the context of XNA.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're really just *dying* to do this, you could do something like this:

```
public static void NormalizeOrZero(this Vector2 ignore, ref Vector2 v2)
{
    if (v2 != Vector2.Zero)
        v2.Normalize();
}
```

You would call it this way:

```
v2.NormalizeOrZero(ref v2);
```

It's mighty ugly, but it'll work, for what it's worth.  But at that point you may as well call a static method in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your second code sample doesn't work but if the first lot of code does what you want you could simply work around it by going:

```
Vector2 v2 = new Vector2()
v2 = v2.NormalizeOrZero();
```

Comment: The second code sample is mutating a copy of the struct, so while it *works* in a sense, it dosesn't do what the OP wants it to do and mutate the object caller has.

Answer (score 0):

You would need both the `ref` and the `this` modifier on the argument, which seems unlikely to work.