# Class vs Struct for data only?

Tags: c++, class, struct

Is there any advantage over using a class over a struct in cases such as these? 
(note: it will only hold variables, there will never be functions)

```
class Foo { 
private:   
   struct Pos { int x, y, z };
public:    
   Pos Position; 
};
```

Versus:

```
struct Foo {
   struct Pos { int x, y, z } Pos;
};
```

---

Similar questions:

- [When should you use a class vs a struct in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585/when-should-you-use-a-class-vs-a-struct-in-c)
- [What are the differences between struct and class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)
- [When should I use a struct instead of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class)

Comment: typo: should be { int x, y, z; }

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no real advantage of using one over the other, in c++, the only difference between a struct and a class is the default visibility of it's members (structs default to public, classes default to private).

Personally, I tend to prefer structs for POD types and use classes for everything else.

EDIT: [litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/litb) made a good point in the comment so I'm going to quote him here:

> one important other difference is that
>   structs derive from other
>   classes/struct public by default,
>   while classes derive privately by
>   default.

Comment: one important other difference is that structs derive from other classes/struct public by default, while classes derive privately by default.

Answer (score 8):

One side point is that structs are often used for aggregate initialized data structures, since all non-static data members must be public anyway (C++03, 8.5.1/1).

```
struct A {  // (valid)
{
   int a;
   int b;
} x = { 1, 2 };

struct A {  // (invalid)
private:
   int a;
   int b;
} x = { 1, 2 };

class A {  // (invalid)
   int a;
   int b;
} x = { 1, 2 };

class A {  // (valid)
public:
   int a;
   int b;
} x = { 1, 2 };

class A {  // (invalid)
public:
   int a;
private:
   int b;
} x = { 1, 2 };
```

Answer (score 6):

`struct` and `class` mean *exactly* the same thing in C++ with the exception that the default access for struct members and bases is public whereas it is private for classes. I tend to chose struct for classes that only have public members and classes for everything else, but it's only a style issue.

Answer (score 3):

The *only* difference between a class and a struct is that struct members are public by default and class members are private by default.  So I say go with whichever one you like best.  I'm sure there are arguments to be made in terms of which one is more readable, but I really don't think it's a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the choice between a struct and a class comes down to your style and how much you want to type.

- If you only have public members in a class/struct you might as well use the struct keyword. It will save you having to type out "public:" later on.
- The other reason to choose a struct over a class would be to implicitly document the intent of the object. So you would make POD types structs (even if they contain a constructors and some static helper methods etc), and you would use class for all the other "regular" classes.

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of the type have no memory allocation issues (such as plain int), then using `struct` is fine if that's the way you want to go and you've made a conscious decision about it that you can justify to those who use your code.  However, if any of the members is a pointer type, then you need to think hard about the memory management issues.  It may still be OK to use a `struct`, but you are much more likely to need a destructor, and some constructors, and so on.  At that point, you want a `class`.

Comment: In C++ it is also possible to add constructors and methods to `struct`s.

Answer (score -1):

"(note: it will only hold variables, there will never be functions)"

Never is a big word.  Usually "never" means "eventually".  Since that's the case, I'd suggest you use a class.  That way, when things change, you don't have so much to change.

The Java (and Python) folks have gotten along fine with everything being a class.   It hasn't hurt them any to not have these specialized method-less classes that C++ calls a "struct".

Comment: Yes, but there are cases in which you must use C++ compound types with C code, system calls etc To emphasize that a C++ data type is, and will remain, nothing more than C plain old data, I prefer to denote it as a struct. In all the other cases, I use classes.

Comment: And consequently refactoring it into a class is pretty trivial in the unlikely case that becomes useful. I bet there's a tool in VS to do it for you - and elsewhere as well if you're not using VS.