# Is this a valid datastructure Map<string, string, string> in C++?

Tags: c++

I have to store 3 strings per variable, but don't know which is the best data structure to use for that in C++.
I can think of only Struct, but not sure if it is the best way to do it.

Something like *string var[100][3]*, first dimension(100) should be dynamically add and remove.

I tried all sorts of things with map, multimap.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Do you *always* have exactly 3, or do you want to "dynamically add and remove"?

Comment: could you give an example of key/values you are storing to make it a little clearer what you need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have always exactly 3 strings together in a triplet and want to have multiple triplets, then define struct with three strings and put it to `std::vector`.

```
struct Triplet {
  std::string a,b,c;
};

std::vector<Triplet> data;
```

Comment: @Ringo you could use classes too, check my answer. But this is beautiful! +1

Comment: Yours also looks good, but what makes you think this is better than using classes?

Comment: @Ringo I said it was beautiful, not better! ;D

Comment: @Ringo @Al Anyway, here's an interesting debate on `Class vs Struct for data only`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/431429/176769

Answer (score 3):

`Map<string, string, string>` is not valid. However, you could create a new data structure with 3 strings and store it in a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class data_structure
{
public:
    string first;
    string second;
    string third;
};


int main()
{
    vector<data_structure> my_vec;

    data_structure elem1;
    elem1.first = "one";
    elem1.second = "two";
    elem1.third = "three";

    my_vec.push_back(elem1);

    data_structure elem2;
    elem2.first = "four";
    elem2.second = "five";
    elem2.third = "six";

    my_vec.push_back(elem2);

    for (int i = 0; i < my_vec.size(); i++)
    {
        // print stuff
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you always want 3 strings, then a [tuple](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.aix.doc/standlib/header_tuple.htm) would require less overhead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

typedef std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string> MyTuple;

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MyTuple t =
        make_tuple(
                std::string("string 1"),
                std::string("string 2"),
                std::string("string 3")
                );

    std::cout
        << std::get<0>(t) << std::endl
        << std::get<1>(t) << std::endl
        << std::get<2>(t) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a class or a [tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html), and store the tuple in a vector

```
std::vector<boost::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string> > v;
boost::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string> t = boost::make_tuple(s1, s2, s3);
v.push_back(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another to the above mix of suggestions: [Boost Tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) (if you have Boost installed already).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/) to store N elements

```
vector<string> three_strings(3);

 three_strings.push_back("one");
 three_strings.push_back("two");
 three_strings.push_back("three");
```

Please note that `tuple` is an alternative, BUT: (1) it is part of `tr1` standard and therefore may not be available on your C++ compiler/installation yet; (2) It stores heterogeneous data (e.g. 3 random type items, not necessarily 3 strings) which may be an overkill

Answer (score 0):

`Map <string , vector <string> >` Will allow you to map a vector of strings to a string key value. If you have the same number of strings mapped to each key then use an array of strings to reduce the memory overhead of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

How about `vector<vector<string> >` ?