# When should I use a struct rather than a class in C#?

Tags: c#, struct

When should you use struct and not class in C#? My conceptual model is that structs are used in times when the item is *merely a collection of value types*.  A way to logically hold them all together into a cohesive whole.

I came across these rules [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110829190107/http://www.johnnycantcode.com/Post/C_Classes_vs._Structs):

- A struct should represent a single
  value.
- A struct should have a memory
  footprint less than 16 bytes.
- A struct should not be changed after
  creation.

Do these rules work? What does a struct mean semantically?

Comment: I can only agree with the first item, structs are used a lot in game programming for example

Comment: `System.Drawing.Rectangle` violates all three of these rules.

Comment: Yes, well parts of them anyway.  I know it is used for portions of games, like NWN2 World Creator.  C is still usually at the core(engine).  XNA Game Studio, Google it :)

Comment: there are quite a few commercial games written in C#, the point is that they are used for optimized code

Comment: I use them sometimes for string valued "enums".

Comment: Another situation where you should use structs is when your objects don't need identity.

Comment: I've always gone by the thinking in the second edit to the question: if I have a handful of related value types, I'll create a struct. I may have several of these small units of data and I don't really want to create a bunch of additional class files for what would only be a few dozen lines of code.

Comment: You use structs when you don't want to inherit your class. This is great if you want to make objects that only hold datas.

Comment: Structures provide better performance when you have small collections of value-types that you want to group together.

This happens all the time in game programming, for example, a vertex in a 3D model will have a position, texture coordinate and a normal, it is also generally going to be immutable.

A single model may have a couple thousand vertices, or it may have a dozen, but structs provide less overhead overall in this usage scenario. I have verified this through my own engine design.

Comment: I would use structs for bridging unmanaged code, and lightweight static type data sets. The tradeoff between performance gain with memory management and lack of extensibility in design.

Comment: That is very much the wrong reason to choose struct over class

Comment: @ErikForbes: I think [this is commonly held as the biggest BCL "oops"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx)

Comment: @ChrisW: The biggest defect in `Rectangle` is that its members are properties rather than fields.  Use of *struct* properties when fields would have sufficed is probably 95% responsible for the "mutable structs are evil" notion (there are legitimate uses for property setters on read-only struct instances; because of that, C# only recently started forbidding their use (shutting out the legitimate use cases); structs which wrapped members in read-write properties effectively turned code that would and should have generated compiler errors into code which would compile but not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use a struct instead of a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class)

Comment: An interesting point could be When should I use Structs with methods because each method sum 1 word (16 bytes) more in references .. so, obviously this struct will be enough heavy to break rule #2 and the performance utility

Comment: @ChrisW Doesnt `System.Drawing.Rectangle` represent a single value? Could you please explain this?

Comment: @MarsonMao It represents a left, a right, a top, a bottom, a height, and a width (i.e. 6 values, admittedly inter-related values).

Comment: @ChrisW I see, but aren't those values represent a rectangle, which is, a "single" value? Like Vector3D or Color, they are also several values inside, but I think they represent single values?

Comment: @MarsonMao One of the defining characteristics of a struct is that it is a group of related values to be treated as a single value. Rectangle certainly satisfies this trait. I think Chris is trying to pick nits with the wording of that bullet point.

Comment: @weberc2 Chris is saying this list should not be used to define whether to use a struct. Counterexample is `Rectangle`: something that most definitely should be a struct, yet violates all of these. Thus they are not good conditions.

Answer (score 689):

The source referenced by the OP has some credibility ...but what about Microsoft - what is the stance on struct usage? I sought some extra [learning from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx), and here is what I found:

> **Consider defining a structure instead of a class if instances of the
>   type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in
>   other objects.**
>
> **Do not define a structure unless the type has all of the following characteristics:**
>
> 1. It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (integer, double, and so on).
> 2. It has an instance size smaller than 16 bytes.
> 3. It is immutable.
> 4. It will not have to be boxed frequently.

### Microsoft consistently violates those rules

Okay, #2 and #3 anyway. Our beloved dictionary has 2 internal structs:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]  // default for structs
private struct Entry  //<Tkey, TValue>
{
    //  View code at *Reference Source
}

[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Enumerator : 
    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IDisposable, 
    IDictionaryEnumerator, IEnumerator
{
    //  View code at *Reference Source
}
```

*[Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,d3599058f8d79be0)

The 'JonnyCantCode.com' source got 3 out of 4 - quite forgivable since #4 probably wouldn't be an issue. If you find yourself boxing a struct, rethink your architecture.

Let's look at why Microsoft would use these structs:

1. Each struct, `Entry` and `Enumerator`, represent single values.
2. Speed
3. `Entry` is never passed as a parameter outside of the Dictionary class. Further investigation shows that in order to satisfy implementation of IEnumerable, Dictionary uses the `Enumerator` struct which it copies every time an enumerator is requested ...makes sense.
4. Internal to the Dictionary class. `Enumerator` is public because Dictionary is enumerable and must have equal accessibility to the IEnumerator interface implementation - e.g. IEnumerator getter.

**Update** - In addition, realize that when a struct implements an interface - as Enumerator does - and is cast to that implemented type, the struct becomes a reference type and is moved to the heap. Internal to the Dictionary class, Enumerator *is* still a value type. However, as soon as a method calls `GetEnumerator()`, a reference-type `IEnumerator` is returned.

What we don't see here is any attempt or proof of requirement to keep structs immutable or maintaining an instance size of only 16 bytes or less:

1. Nothing in the structs above is declared `readonly` - **not** immutable
2. Size of these struct could be well over 16 bytes
3. `Entry` has an undetermined lifetime (from `Add()`, to `Remove()`, `Clear()`, or garbage collection);

And ...
 4. Both structs store TKey and TValue, which we all know are quite capable of being reference types (added bonus info)

Hashed keys notwithstanding, dictionaries are fast in part because instancing a struct is quicker than a reference type. Here, I have a `Dictionary<int, int>` that stores 300,000 random integers with sequentially incremented keys.

> Capacity: 312874
>   MemSize:  2660827 bytes
>   Completed Resize:  5ms
>   Total time to fill:  889ms

**Capacity**:  number of elements available before the internal array must be resized.

**MemSize**:  determined by serializing the dictionary into a MemoryStream and getting a byte length (accurate enough for our purposes).

**Completed Resize**:  the time it takes to resize the internal array from 150862 elements to 312874 elements. When you figure that each element is sequentially copied via `Array.CopyTo()`, that ain't too shabby.

**Total time to fill**: admittedly skewed due to logging and an `OnResize` event I added to the source; however, still impressive to fill 300k integers while resizing 15 times during the operation. Just out of curiosity, what would the total time to fill be if I already knew the capacity? **13ms**

So, now, what if `Entry` were a class? Would these times or metrics really differ that much?

> Capacity:  312874
>   MemSize:  2660827 bytes
>   Completed Resize:  26ms
>   Total time to fill:  964ms

Obviously, the big difference is in resizing. Any difference if Dictionary is initialized with the Capacity? Not enough to be concerned with ... **12ms**.

What happens is, because `Entry` is a struct, it does not require initialization like a reference type. This is both the beauty and the bane of the value type. In order to use `Entry` as a reference type, I had to insert the following code:

```
/*
 *  Added to satisfy initialization of entry elements --
 *  this is where the extra time is spent resizing the Entry array
 * **/
for (int i = 0 ; i < prime ; i++)
{
    destinationArray[i] = new Entry( );
}
/*  *********************************************** */
```

The reason I had to initialize each array element of `Entry` as a reference type can be found at [MSDN: Structure Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229031.aspx). In short:

> **Do not provide a default constructor for a structure.**
>
> If a structure defines a default constructor, when arrays of the
>   structure are created, the common language runtime automatically
>   executes the default constructor on each array element.
>
> Some compilers, such as the C# compiler, do not allow structures to
>   have default constructors.

It is actually quite simple and we will borrow from [Asimov's *Three Laws of Robotics*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Laws_of_Robotics):

1. The struct must be safe to use
2. The struct must perform its function efficiently, unless this would violate rule #1
3. The struct must remain intact during its use unless its destruction is required to satisfy rule #1

...*what do we take away from this*: in short, be responsible with the use of value types. They are quick and efficient, but have the ability to cause many unexpected behaviors if not properly maintained (i.e. unintentional copies).

Comment: I don't think the runtime ever calls any struct constructor when creating an array of struct.  The reason most languages forbid structs from having a default constructor is not because calling them would make array construction inefficient, but rather because it would be confusing to have struct constructors called in some cases but not others.

Comment: As for Microsoft's rules, the rule about immutability seems to be designed to discourage use of value types in a such a way that their behavior would differ from those of reference types, notwithstanding the fact that *piecewise-mutable value semantics can be useful*.  If having a type be piecewise-mutable would make it easier to work with, and if storage locations of the type should be logically detached from each other, the type should be a "mutable" struct.

Comment: The fact that many of Microsoft's types violate those rules does not represent a problem with those types, but rather indicates that the rules should not apply to all structure types. If a structure represents a single entity [as with `Decimal` or `DateTime`], then if it would not abide by the other three rules, it should be replaced by a class. If a structure holds a fixed collection of variables, each of which may hold any value that would be valid for its type [e.g. `Rectangle`], then it should abide by *different* rules, some of which are contrary to those for "single-value" structs.

Comment: @supercat: you pretty well summed up my dissertation in a small paragraph :)

Comment: @IAbstract: Some people would justify the `Dictionary` entry type on the basis that it's an internal type only, performance was considered more important than semantics, or some other excuse.  My point is that a type like `Rectangle` should have its contents exposed as individually-editable fields not "because" the performance benefits outweigh the resulting semantic imperfections, but because *the type semantically represents a fixed set of independent values*, and so the mutable struct is both more performant and semantically *superior*.

Comment: @IAbstract: If I had the power to change one early document from .net, it would probably be that one about structures.  Were I writing the document, I would suggest that structures should to the extent possible fit one of two patterns--either the one described, or else *a collection of independent public fields*.  In cases where the latter is what's needed, I think it's crazy to suggest that one should make structures pretend to be immutable class objects, which can do only awkwardly the things that exposed-field structures can do well.

Comment: @supercat: I agree ... and the whole point of my answer was that the 'guidelines' are pretty weak and structs should be used with full knowledge and understanding of the behaviors. See my answer on mutable struct here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108920/why-is-it-okay-that-this-struct-is-mutable-when-are-mutable-structs-acceptable/8109254#8109254

Comment: @IAbstract: Yup.  My point was that the "immutable structs are evil" people make an exception for internal-only performance-critical types like those to which you refer, but the real exception should be much broader.  BTW, do you like my ".net is not Java" comment?

Comment: this is interesting if you make a contrast to C/C++, where the recommended way is to pass objects by value

Comment: @IonTodirel: if I were qualified to make the contrast I would. :) I don't know C/C++ well enough to go there. However, that is why the question is tagged for C#.

Comment: @IonTodirel: I thought the recommended C++ approach was to pass the values of object either by reference or by "const reference"; the C# approach when using class types is equivalent to passing pointers to objects, which is disparaged in C++ in cases where it isn't necessary.

Comment: @supercat, certainly, I was referring to special cases where you need to transport copies from a function/thread to another, because the original is subject to destruction or invalidation

Comment: @IonTodirel: That makes sense.  The real key there is that in cases where an object defines a sensible means of copying, such means is a language feature rather than being an inconsistently-implemented interface.

Comment: I wonder if the increasing tendency towards 64-bit architecture weighs on the 16-byte advice by Microsoft?  If I compile a struct in a dll with 32-bit, everything comes out as 4-byte members.  If I compile it and tell Visual Studio to target "Any CPU", everything comes out as 8-byte members.  I think Microsoft technically meant "no more than 16-bytes", as opposed to "less than 16-bytes", but does the general rule of thumb that people should follow (whether Microsoft's advice or not) say to just use structs with four or less *members*, whether they are references, values, or both?

Comment: @Panzercrisis: *Microsoft technically meant "**no more** than 16-bytes"* ...I agree this could be the case. When maintained as a `Value` type, then following the *rule of thumb* would infer 4 or fewer members. If the struct is cast to an interface (becoming a `Reference` type), then I would completely ignore the *rule of thumb* personally. This could very well be the reason that the `Dictionary`'s enumerator has reference type members and is certainly larger than 16 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for the great info.  I would add that, although it is true that calling GetEnumerator though the enumerator would move it to the heap, this does not happen in practice unless you manually cast it to an interface.  The C# compiler will not use the interface unless it cannot find appropriately named methods with the appropriate signatures, specifically to avoid boxing.  So they did not really violate rule #4 here.  They modified the compiler itself to avoid that.

Comment: What is boxing? "4. It will not have to be boxed frequently"

Comment: @minseong ... see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing

Answer (score 195):

Whenever you:

1. don't need polymorphism,
2. want value semantics, and
3. want to avoid heap allocation and the associated garbage collection overhead.

The caveat, however, is that structs (arbitrarily large) are more expensive to pass around than class references (usually one machine word), so classes could end up being faster in practice.

Comment: That is only one "caveat". Should also consider "lifting" of value-types and cases such as `(Guid)null` (it's okay to cast a null to a reference-type), among other things.

Comment: more expensive than in C/C++? in C++ the recommended way is to pass objects by value

Comment: @IonTodirel Wasn't that for memory safety reasons, rather than performance? It's always a trade-off, but passing 32 B by stack is always(TM) going to be slower than passing a 4 B reference by register. *However*, also note that the use of "value / reference" is a bit different in C# and C++ - when you pass a reference to an object, you're still passing by value, even though you're passing a reference (you're passing the value of the reference, not a reference to the reference, basically). It's not value *semantics*, but it's technically "pass-by-value".

Comment: @Luaan Copying is only one aspect of costs. The extra indirection due to pointer/reference also costs per access. In some cases the struct can even be moved and thus doesn't even need to be copied.

Answer (score 179):

I do not agree with the rules given in the original post. Here are my rules:

1. You use structs for performance when stored in arrays. (see also [When are structs the answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597259/when-are-structs-the-answer/598182#598182))
2. You need them in code passing structured data to/from C/C++
3. Do not use structs unless you need them:

   - They behave different from "normal objects" (*reference types*) under assignment and
     when passing as arguments, which can lead to unexpected behavior;
     this is particularly dangerous if the person looking at the code does
     not know they are dealing with a struct.
   - They cannot be inherited.
   - Passing structs as arguments is more expensive than classes.

Comment: +1 Yes, I agree on #1 entirely (this is a *huge* advantage when dealing with things like images, etc) and for pointing out that they *are different* from "normal objects" and there is *know way of knowing this* except by existing knowledge or examining the type itself. Also, you can't cast a null value to a struct type :-) This is actually one case where I *almost* wish there was some 'Hungarian' for non-Core value-types or a mandatory 'struct' keyword at variable declaration site.

Comment: @pst: It is true that one has to know something is a `struct` to know how it will behave, but if something is a `struct` with exposed fields, that's all one has to know.  If an object exposes a property of an exposed-field-struct type, and if code reads that struct to a variable and modifies, one can safely predict that such action will not affect the object whose property was read unless or until the struct is written back.  By contrast, if the property were a mutable class type, reading it and modifying it might update the underlying object as expected, but...

Comment: ...it might also end up changing nothing, or it might change or corrupt objects that one didn't intend to change.  Having code whose semantics say "change this variable all you like; changes won't do anything until you explicitly store them someplace" seems clearer than having code which says "You're getting a reference to some object, which might shared with any number of other references, or might not be shared at all; you'll have to figure out who else might have references to this object to know what will happen if you change it."

Comment: Spot on with #1. A list full of structs can squeeze much more relevant data into L1/L2 caches than a list full of object references, (for the right size struct).

Comment: Inheritance is rarely the right tool for the job, and reasoning too much about performance without profiling is a bad idea. Firstly, structs can be passed by reference. Secondly, passing by reference or by value is rarely a significant performance issue. Lastly, you're not accounting for the additional heap allocation and garbage collection that needs to take place for a class. Personally, I prefer to think of structs as plain-old-data and classes as things that *do* things (objects) although you can define methods on structs as well.

Comment: @ILoveFortran "Passing structs as arguments is more expensive than classes." - In that case, how come primitives such as `Int32` are implemented as structs instead of classes?

Comment: @ILoveFortran couldn't you just as easily say that objects behave differently to "normal structs" and if the person doesn't know they are dealing with an object rather than a struct, they might assume the value is copied when passed as a param to a method.

Comment: I have said the exact same thing (#3) to people around me for years and years. It's nice to see it in your answer ❤️

Answer (score 96):

Use a struct when you want value semantics as opposed to reference semantics.

If you need reference semantics you need a class not a struct.

Comment: Everyone knows that. Seems like he's looking for more than a "struct is a value type" answer.

Comment: It the most basic case and should be stated for anyone who reads this post and doesn't know that.

Comment: Not that this answer isn't true; it obviously is. That's not really the point.

Comment: @Josh: For anyone who doesn't know it already, simply saying it is an insufficient answer, since it's quite likely they don't know what it means, either.

Comment: I've just downvoted this because I think one of the other answers should be at the top - any answer that says "For interop with unmanaged code, otherwise avoid".

Comment: *sigh* Answers like these are the reason why I have to post a tutorial on basic elements of a language in my **questions** because people would rather give the answer to simple things than actually read the question.

Comment: +1 for focusing on semantics. Of more people would program more based on paradigms and semantics we would not have all these language/platform/api/format wars.

Comment: A class can be checked against null, so you know whether it has been initalized properly. With a struct you are never sure (see default(struct)). See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/xwth0h0d.aspx

Comment: @MikedeKlerk Not sure why that would matter. If uninitialized structs are causing issues in C#, then you've got bigger problems.

Comment: This really doesn't hold, especially now we have records

Comment: You do not have to use a struct when you need value semantics. You can achieve that using a class and following the [value object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object). The modern keyword `record` makes that convenient. Also, it is possible to create a struct that is mutable, violating what is usually required to say it has value semantics.

Answer (score 67):

In addition to the "it is a value" answer, one specific scenario for using structs is when you ***know*** that you have a set of data that is causing garbage collection issues, and you have lots of objects. For example, a large list/array of Person instances. The natural metaphor here is a class, but if you have large number of long-lived Person instance, they can end up clogging GEN-2 and causing GC stalls. If the scenario warrants it, one potential approach here is to use an array (not list) of Person **structs**, i.e. `Person[]`. Now, instead of having millions of objects in GEN-2, you have a single chunk on the LOH (I'm assuming no strings etc here - i.e. a pure value without any references). This has very little GC impact.

Working with this data is awkward, as the data is probably over-sized for a struct, and you don't want to copy fat values all the time. However, accessing it directly in an array does not copy the struct - it is in-place (contrast to a list indexer, which does copy). This means lots of work with indexes:

```
int index = ...
int id = peopleArray[index].Id;
```

Note that keeping the values themselves immutable will help here. For more complex logic, use a method with a by-ref parameter:

```
void Foo(ref Person person) {...}
...
Foo(ref peopleArray[index]);
```

Again, this is in-place - we have not copied the value.

In very specific scenarios, this tactic can be very successful; however, it is a fairly advanced scernario that should be attempted only if you know what you are doing and why. The default here would be a class.

Comment: I wonder what performance would be like if one defined an `ICustomer`, and had a `CustomerRef` struct which implemented that interface, held a single `int` index, and acted in appropriate fashion upon the items of the array?  I would think that if one made the methods which take a `Customer` instead accept an `ICustomer` generically it should be possible to get performance comparable to the current approach without having to widely expose the underlying array.

Comment: Such a thing is probably a YAGNI, but if e.g. the customer array would be in danger of hitting the 2GB limit, one could change the array-access code from `customers[index]` to `customers[index >> 16][index & 65535]` without having to affect anything outside `CustomerRef`.

Comment: @supercat or just enable the large array support in 4.5

Comment: @MarcGravell: Never used that.  In any case, my point was that there are various means via which the `ICustomer` approach would allow one to migrate away from using a monolithic array should the need arise (the 2GB limit was one reason why it might do so, but not the only one).  Incidentally, one thing your blog doesn't mention as a "cost" of your approach is that the GC has no way of knowing which array slots have references to them.  That reduces the cost of GC, but means it may be necessary for an application to track such things itself.

Comment: @MarcGravell Why did you mention : _use an array (not list)_ ? `List` I believe , uses an `Array` behind scenes. no ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I was curious about this as well, but I believe the answer lies in the second paragraph of Marc's answer. "However, accessing it directly in an array does not copy the struct - it is in-place (contrast to a list indexer, which does copy)."

Answer (score 47):

From the [C# Language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx):

> **1.7 Structs**
>
> Like classes, structs are data structures that can contain data members and function members, but unlike classes, structs are
>   value types and do not require heap allocation. A variable of a struct
>   type directly stores the data of the struct, whereas a variable of a
>   class type stores a reference to a dynamically allocated object.
>   Struct types do not support user-specified inheritance, and all struct
>   types implicitly inherit from type object.
>
> Structs are particularly useful for small data structures that have
>   value semantics. Complex numbers, points in a coordinate system, or
>   key-value pairs in a dictionary are all good examples of structs. The
>   use of structs rather than classes for small data structures can make
>   a large difference in the number of memory allocations an application
>   performs. For example, the following program creates and initializes
>   an array of 100 points. With Point implemented as a class, 101
>   separate objects are instantiated—one for the array and one each for
>   the 100 elements.

```
class Point
{
   public int x, y;

   public Point(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }
}

class Test
{
   static void Main() {
      Point[] points = new Point[100];
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) points[i] = new Point(i, i);
   }
}
```

An alternative is to make Point a struct.

```
struct Point
{
   public int x, y;

   public Point(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }
}
```

Now, only one object is instantiated—the one for the array—and the Point instances are stored in-line in the array.

Struct constructors are invoked with the new operator, but that does not imply that memory is being allocated. Instead of dynamically allocating an object and returning a reference to it, a struct constructor simply returns the struct value itself (typically in a temporary location on the stack), and this value is then copied as necessary.

With classes, it is possible for two variables to reference the same object and thus possible for operations on one variable to affect the object referenced by the other variable. With structs, the variables each have their own copy of the data, and it is not possible for operations on one to affect the other. For example, the output produced by the following code fragment depends on whether Point is a class or a struct.

```
Point a = new Point(10, 10);
Point b = a;
a.x = 20;
Console.WriteLine(b.x);
```

If Point is a class, the output is 20 because a and b reference the same object. If Point is a struct, the output is 10 because the assignment of a to b creates a copy of the value, and this copy is unaffected by the subsequent assignment to a.x.

The previous example highlights two of the limitations of structs. First, copying an entire struct is typically less efficient than copying an object reference, so assignment and value parameter passing can be more expensive with structs than with reference types. Second, except for ref and out parameters, it is not possible to create references to structs, which rules out their usage in a number of situations.

Comment: While the fact that references to structs cannot be persisted is sometimes a limitation, it is also a very useful characteristic.  One of the major weaknesses of .net is that there is no decent way to pass outside code a reference to a mutable object without forever losing control of that object.  By contrast, one may safely give an outside method a `ref` to a mutable struct and know that any mutations that outside method will perform on it will be done before it returns.  It's too bad .net doesn't have any concept of ephemeral parameters and function return values, since...

Comment: ...that would allow the advantageous semantics of structs passed by `ref` to be achieved with class objects.  Essentially, local variables, parameters, and function return values could be persistable (default), returnable, or ephemeral.  Code would be forbidden from copying ephemeral things to anything that would outlive the present scope.  Returnable things would be like ephemeral things except that they could be returned from a function.  The return value of a function would be bound by the tightest restrictions applicable to any of its "returnable" parameters.

Answer (score 41):

Here is a basic rule.

- If all member fields are value types create a **struct**.
- If any one member field is a reference type, create a **class**. This is because the reference type field will need the  heap allocation anyway.

**Exmaples**

```
public struct MyPoint 
{
    public int X; // Value Type
    public int Y; // Value Type
}

public class MyPointWithName 
{
    public int X; // Value Type
    public int Y; // Value Type
    public string Name; // Reference Type
}
```

Comment: Immutable reference types like `string` are semantically equivalent to values, and storing a reference to an immutable object into a field does not entail a heap allocation.  The difference between a struct with exposed public fields and a class object with exposed public fields is that given the code sequence `var q=p; p.X=4; q.X=5;`, `p.X` will have the value 4 if `a` is a structure type, and 5 if it's a class type.  If one wishes to be able to conveniently modify the members of the type, one should select 'class' or 'struct' based upon whether one wants changes to `q` to affect `p`.

Comment: Yes i agree the reference variable will be on the stack but the object it refers will exist on the heap. Although structs and classes behave differently when assigned to a different variable, but i don't think thats a strong deciding factor.

Comment: Mutable structs and mutable classes behave completely differently; if one is right, the other will most likely be wrong.  I'm not sure how behavior wouldn't be a deciding factor in determining whether to use a struct or a class.

Comment: I said it’s not a strong deciding factor because often when when you are creating a class or struct you are not sure how it will be used. So you concentrate on how things make more sense from design perspective. Anyways i have never seen at a single place in .NET library where a struct contains a reference variable.

Comment: Structure type `ArraySegment<T>` encapsulates a `T[]`, which is always a class type.  Structure type `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` is often used with class types as the generic parameters.

Comment: `BitVector32` is broken per your example as it uses a 32-byte array which is a reference type. This is not a hard and fast way to determine whether you need a struct.

Comment: This is the best answer. If you need a Value semantics, use a struct (passing by argument generate a copy instead of allowing editing the original). It is possible for big collections of data a `struct` actually improve performance but that should be verified by profiling and shipped with unit tests showing you not altered the functionality of the program. If you want to include part of this comment in the answer as edit feel free to do that ^^

Answer (score 38):

Structs are good for atomic representation of data, where the said data can be copied multiple times by the code. Cloning an object is in general more expensive than copying a struct, as it involves allocating the memory, running the constructor and deallocating/garbage collection when done with it.

Comment: Yes, but large structs can be more expensive than class references (when passing around to methods).

Answer (score 20):

First: Interop scenarios or when you need to specify the memory layout

Second: When the data is almost the same size as a reference pointer anyway.

Answer (score 19):

I made a small benchmark with [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) to get a better understanding of "struct" benefit in numbers. I'm testing looping through array (or list) of structs (or classes). Creating those arrays or lists is out of the benchmark's scope - it is clear that "class" is more heavy will utilize more memory, and will involve GC.

So the conclusion is: be careful with LINQ and hidden structs boxing/unboxing and using structs for microoptimizations strictly stay with arrays.

P.S. Another benchmark about passing struct/class through call stack is there https://stackoverflow.com/a/47864451/506147

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.8, OS=Windows 10 Redstone 2 (10.0.15063)
Processor=Intel Core i5-2500K CPU 3.30GHz (Sandy Bridge), ProcessorCount=4
Frequency=3233542 Hz, Resolution=309.2584 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host] : Clr 4.0.30319.42000, 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.2101.1
  Clr    : Clr 4.0.30319.42000, 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.2101.1
  Core   : .NET Core 4.6.25211.01, 64bit RyuJIT


          Method |  Job | Runtime |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev |       Min |       Max |    Median | Rank |  Gen 0 | Allocated |
---------------- |----- |-------- |----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|----------:|-----:|-------:|----------:|
   TestListClass |  Clr |     Clr |  5.599 us | 0.0408 us | 0.0382 us |  5.561 us |  5.689 us |  5.583 us |    3 |      - |       0 B |
  TestArrayClass |  Clr |     Clr |  2.024 us | 0.0102 us | 0.0096 us |  2.011 us |  2.043 us |  2.022 us |    2 |      - |       0 B |
  TestListStruct |  Clr |     Clr |  8.427 us | 0.1983 us | 0.2204 us |  8.101 us |  9.007 us |  8.374 us |    5 |      - |       0 B |
 TestArrayStruct |  Clr |     Clr |  1.539 us | 0.0295 us | 0.0276 us |  1.502 us |  1.577 us |  1.537 us |    1 |      - |       0 B |
   TestLinqClass |  Clr |     Clr | 13.117 us | 0.1007 us | 0.0892 us | 13.007 us | 13.301 us | 13.089 us |    7 | 0.0153 |      80 B |
  TestLinqStruct |  Clr |     Clr | 28.676 us | 0.1837 us | 0.1534 us | 28.441 us | 28.957 us | 28.660 us |    9 |      - |      96 B |
   TestListClass | Core |    Core |  5.747 us | 0.1147 us | 0.1275 us |  5.567 us |  5.945 us |  5.756 us |    4 |      - |       0 B |
  TestArrayClass | Core |    Core |  2.023 us | 0.0299 us | 0.0279 us |  1.990 us |  2.069 us |  2.013 us |    2 |      - |       0 B |
  TestListStruct | Core |    Core |  8.753 us | 0.1659 us | 0.1910 us |  8.498 us |  9.110 us |  8.670 us |    6 |      - |       0 B |
 TestArrayStruct | Core |    Core |  1.552 us | 0.0307 us | 0.0377 us |  1.496 us |  1.618 us |  1.552 us |    1 |      - |       0 B |
   TestLinqClass | Core |    Core | 14.286 us | 0.2430 us | 0.2273 us | 13.956 us | 14.678 us | 14.313 us |    8 | 0.0153 |      72 B |
  TestLinqStruct | Core |    Core | 30.121 us | 0.5941 us | 0.5835 us | 28.928 us | 30.909 us | 30.153 us |   10 |      - |      88 B |
```

Code:

```
[RankColumn, MinColumn, MaxColumn, StdDevColumn, MedianColumn]
    [ClrJob, CoreJob]
    [HtmlExporter, MarkdownExporter]
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    public class BenchmarkRef
    {
        public class C1
        {
            public string Text1;
            public string Text2;
            public string Text3;
        }

        public struct S1
        {
            public string Text1;
            public string Text2;
            public string Text3;
        }

        List<C1> testListClass = new List<C1>();
        List<S1> testListStruct = new List<S1>();
        C1[] testArrayClass;
        S1[] testArrayStruct;
        public BenchmarkRef()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
            {
                testListClass.Add(new C1  { Text1= i.ToString(), Text2=null, Text3= i.ToString() });
                testListStruct.Add(new S1 { Text1 = i.ToString(), Text2 = null, Text3 = i.ToString() });
            }
            testArrayClass = testListClass.ToArray();
            testArrayStruct = testListStruct.ToArray();
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int TestListClass()
        {
            var x = 0;
            foreach(var i in testListClass)
            {
                x += i.Text1.Length + i.Text3.Length;
            }
            return x;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int TestArrayClass()
        {
            var x = 0;
            foreach (var i in testArrayClass)
            {
                x += i.Text1.Length + i.Text3.Length;
            }
            return x;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int TestListStruct()
        {
            var x = 0;
            foreach (var i in testListStruct)
            {
                x += i.Text1.Length + i.Text3.Length;
            }
            return x;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int TestArrayStruct()
        {
            var x = 0;
            foreach (var i in testArrayStruct)
            {
                x += i.Text1.Length + i.Text3.Length;
            }
            return x;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int TestLinqClass()
        {
            var x = testListClass.Select(i=> i.Text1.Length + i.Text3.Length).Sum();
            return x;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int TestLinqStruct()
        {
            var x = testListStruct.Select(i => i.Text1.Length + i.Text3.Length).Sum();
            return x;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you figured out why structs are so much slower when used in lists and such? Is it because of the hidden boxing and unboxing that you've mentioned? If so why does it happen?

Comment: Accessing struct in array should be quicker just because of no additional referencing required. Boxing/Unboxing is case for linq.

Answer (score 18):

You need to use a "struct" in situations where you want to explicitly specify memory layout using the [StructLayoutAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) - typically for PInvoke.

Edit: Comment points out that you can use class or struct with StructLayoutAttribute and that is certainly true. In practice, you would typically use a struct - it is allocated on the stack vs the heap which makes sense if you are just passing an argument to an unmanaged method call.

Comment: The StructLayoutAttribute can be applied to structs or classes so this is not a reason to use structs.

Comment: Why does it make sense if you are just passing an argument to an unmanaged method call?

Answer (score 16):

I use structs for packing or unpacking any sort of binary communication format. That includes reading or writing to disk, DirectX vertex lists, network protocols, or dealing with encrypted/compressed data.

The three guidelines you list haven't been useful for me in this context. When I need to write out four hundred bytes of stuff in a Particular Order, I'm gonna define a four-hundred-byte struct, and I'm gonna fill it with whatever unrelated values it's supposed to have, and I'm going to set it up whatever way makes the most sense at the time. (Okay, four hundred bytes would be pretty strange-- but back when I was writing Excel files for a living, I was dealing with structs of up to about forty bytes all over, because that's how big some of the BIFF records ARE.)

Comment: Couldn't you just as easily use a reference type for that though?

Answer (score 16):

**MYTH #1: STRUCTS ARE LIGHTWEIGHT CLASSES**

This myth comes in a variety of forms. Some people believe that value types can’t or
shouldn’t have methods or other significant behavior—they should be used as simple
data transfer types, with just public fields or simple properties. The DateTime type is a
good counterexample to this: it makes sense for it to be a value type, in terms of being
a fundamental unit like a number or a character, and it also makes sense for it to be
able to perform calculations based on its value. Looking at things from the other
direction, data transfer types should often be reference types anyway—the decision
should be based on the desired value or reference type semantics, not the simplicity of
the type.
 Other people believe that value types are “lighter” than reference types in terms
of performance. The truth is that in some cases value types are more performant—
they don’t require garbage collection unless they’re boxed, don’t have the type
identification overhead, and don’t require dereferencing, for example. But in other
ways, reference types are more performant—parameter passing, assigning values to
variables, returning values, and similar operations only require 4 or 8 bytes to becopied (depending on whether you’re running the 32-bit or 64-bit CLR) rather than
copying all the data. Imagine if ArrayList were somehow a “pure” value type, and
passing an ArrayList expression to a method involved copying all its data! In almost
all cases, performance isn’t really determined by this sort of decision anyway. Bottlenecks are almost never where you think they’ll be, and before you make a design decision based on performance, you should measure the different options.
 It’s worth noting that the combination of the two beliefs doesn’t work either. It
doesn’t matter how many methods a type has (whether it’s a class or a struct)—the
memory taken per instance isn’t affected. (There’s a cost in terms of the memory
taken up for the code itself, but that’s incurred once rather than for each instance.)

**MYTH #2: REFERENCE TYPES LIVE ON THE HEAP; VALUE TYPES LIVE ON THE STACK**

This one is often caused by laziness on the part of the person repeating it. The first
part is correct—an instance of a reference type is always created on the heap. It’s the
second part that causes problems. As I’ve already noted, a variable’s value lives wherever it’s declared, so if you have a class with an instance variable of type int, that variable’s value for any given object will always be where the rest of the data for the object
is—on the heap. Only local variables (variables declared within methods) and method
parameters live on the stack. In C# 2 and later, even some local variables don’t really
live on the stack, as you’ll see when we look at anonymous methods in chapter 5.
ARE THESE CONCEPTS RELEVANT NOW? It’s arguable that if you’re writing managed code, you should let the runtime worry about how memory is best used.
Indeed, the language specification makes no guarantees about what lives
where; a future runtime may be able to create some objects on the stack if it
knows it can get away with it, or the C# compiler could generate code that
hardly uses the stack at all.
The next myth is usually just a terminology issue.

**MYTH #3: OBJECTS ARE PASSED BY REFERENCE IN C# BY DEFAULT**

This is probably the most widely propagated myth. Again, the people who make this
claim often (though not always) know how C# actually behaves, but they don’t know
what “pass by reference” really means. Unfortunately, this is confusing for people who
do know what it means.
 The formal definition of pass by reference is relatively complicated, involving l-values
and similar computer-science terminology, but the important thing is that if you pass a
variable by reference, the method you’re calling can change the value of the caller’s variable by changing its parameter value. Now, remember that the value of a reference
type variable is the reference, not the object itself. You can change the contents of the
object that a parameter refers to without the parameter itself being passed by reference. For instance, the following method changes the contents of the StringBuilder
object in question, but the caller’s expression will still refer to the same object as
before:

```
void AppendHello(StringBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Append("hello");
}
```

When this method is called, the parameter value (a reference to a StringBuilder) is
passed by value. If you were to change the value of the builder variable within the
method—for example, with the statement builder = null;—that change wouldn’t be
seen by the caller, contrary to the myth.
 It’s interesting to note that not only is the “by reference” bit of the myth inaccurate, but so is the “objects are passed” bit. Objects themselves are never passed, either
by reference or by value. When a reference type is involved, either the variable is
passed by reference or the value of the argument (the reference) is passed by value.
Aside from anything else, this answers the question of what happens when null is
used as a by-value argument—if objects were being passed around, that would cause
issues, as there wouldn’t be an object to pass! Instead, the null reference is passed by
value in the same way as any other reference would be.
 If this quick explanation has left you bewildered, you might want to look at my article, “Parameter passing in C#,” (http://mng.bz/otVt), which goes into much more
detail.
 These myths aren’t the only ones around. Boxing and unboxing come in for their
fair share of misunderstanding, which I’ll try to clear up next.

**Reference:** C# in Depth 3rd Edition by Jon Skeet

Answer (score 15):

With the exception of the valuetypes that are used directly by the runtime and various others for PInvoke purposes, you should only use valuetypes in 2 scenarios.

1. When you need copy semantics.
2. When you need automatic initialization, normally in arrays of these types.

Comment: #2 seems to be *part* of the reason for struct prevalence in .Net collection classes..

Comment: If the first thing one would do upon creating a storage location of a class type would be to create a new instance of that type, store a reference to it in that location, and never copy the reference anywhere else nor overwrite it, then a struct and class would behave identically. Structs have a convenient standard way to copy all of the fields from one instance to another, and will generally offer better performance in cases where one would never duplicate a reference to a class (except for the ephemeral `this` parameter used to invoke its methods); classes allow one to duplicate references.

Answer (score 15):

.NET supports `value types` and `reference types` (in Java, you can define only reference types). Instances of `reference types` get allocated in the managed heap and are garbage collected when there are no outstanding references to them. Instances of `value types`, on the other hand, are allocated in the `stack`, and hence allocated memory is reclaimed as soon as their scope ends. And of course, `value types` get passed by value, and `reference types` by reference. All C# primitive data types, except for System.String, are value types.

**When to use struct over class,**

In C#, `structs` are `value types`, classes are `reference types`. You can create value types, in C#, using the `enum` keyword and the `struct` keyword. Using a `value type` instead of a `reference type` will result in fewer objects on the managed heap, which results in lesser load on the garbage collector (GC), less frequent GC cycles, and consequently better performance. However, `value types` have their downsides too. Passing around a big `struct` is definitely costlier than passing a reference, that's one obvious problem. The other problem is the overhead associated with `boxing/unboxing`. In case you're wondering what `boxing/unboxing` mean, follow these links for a good explanation on `boxing` and `unboxing`. Apart from performance, there are times when you simply need types to have value semantics, which would be very difficult (or ugly) to implement if `reference types` are all you have. You should use `value types` only, When you need copy semantics or need automatic initialization, normally in `arrays` of these types.

Comment: Copying small structures or passing by value is as cheap as copying or passing a class reference, or passing the structures by `ref`.  Passing any size structure by `ref` costs the same as passing a class reference by value.  Copying any size structure or passing by value is cheaper than performing a defensive copy of a class object and storing or passing a reference to that.  The big times classes are better than structs for storing values are (1) when the classes are immutable (so as to avoid defensive copying), and each instance which is created will be passed around a lot, or...

Comment: ...(2) when for various reasons a struct would simply not be usable [e.g. because one needs to use nested references for something like a tree, or because one needs polymorphism].  Note that when using value types, one should generally expose fields directly absent a particular reason not to (whereas with most class types fields should be wrapped within properties).  Many of the so-called "evils" of mutable value types stem from needless wrapping of fields in properties (e.g. while some compilers would allow one to call a property setter on a read-only struct because it would sometimes...

Comment: ...do the right thing, all compilers would properly reject attempts to directly set fields on such structures; the best way to ensure compilers reject `readOnlyStruct.someMember = 5;` is not to make `someMember` a read-only property, but instead make it a field.

Answer (score 15):

A **struct** is a value type.  If you assign a struct to a new variable, the new variable will contain a copy of the original.

```
public struct IntStruct {
    public int Value {get; set;}
}
```

Excecution of the following results in **5 instances** of the struct stored in memory:

```
var struct1 = new IntStruct() { Value = 0 }; // original
var struct2 = struct1;  // A copy is made
var struct3 = struct2;  // A copy is made
var struct4 = struct3;  // A copy is made
var struct5 = struct4;  // A copy is made

// NOTE: A "copy" will occur when you pass a struct into a method parameter.
// To avoid the "copy", use the ref keyword.

// Although structs are designed to use less system resources
// than classes.  If used incorrectly, they could use significantly more.
```

A **class** is a reference type.  When you assign a class to a new variable, the variable contains a reference to the original class object.

```
public class IntClass {
    public int Value {get; set;}
}
```

Excecution of the following results in **only one instance** of the class object in memory.

```
var class1 = new IntClass() { Value = 0 };
var class2 = class1;  // A reference is made to class1
var class3 = class2;  // A reference is made to class1
var class4 = class3;  // A reference is made to class1
var class5 = class4;  // A reference is made to class1
```

**Struct**s may increase the likelihood of a code mistake.  If a value object is treated like a mutable reference object, a developer may be surprised when changes made are unexpectedly lost.

```
var struct1 = new IntStruct() { Value = 0 };
var struct2 = struct1;
struct2.Value = 1;
// At this point, a developer may be surprised when 
// struct1.Value is 0 and not 1
```

Answer (score 11):

Structure types in C# or other .net languages are generally used to hold things that should behave like fixed-sized groups of values.  A useful aspect of structure types is that the fields of a structure-type instance can be modified by modifying the storage location in which it is held, and in no other way.  It's possible to code a structure in such a way that the only way to mutate any field is to construct a whole new instance and then use a struct assignment to mutate all the fields of the target by overwriting them with values from the new instance, but unless a struct provides no means of creating an instance where its fields have non-default values, all of its fields will be mutable if and if the struct itself is stored in a mutable location.

Note that it's possible to design a structure type so that it will essentially behave like a class type, if the structure contains a private class-type field, and redirects its own members to that of the wrapped class object.  For example, a `PersonCollection` might offer properties `SortedByName` and `SortedById`, both of which hold an "immutable" reference to a `PersonCollection` (set in their constructor) and implement `GetEnumerator` by calling either `creator.GetNameSortedEnumerator` or `creator.GetIdSortedEnumerator`.  Such structs would behave much like a reference to a `PersonCollection`, except that their `GetEnumerator` methods would be bound to different methods in the `PersonCollection`.  One could also have a structure wrap a portion of an array (e.g. one could define an `ArrayRange<T>` structure which would hold a `T[]` called `Arr`, an int `Offset`, and an int `Length`, with an indexed property which, for an index `idx` in the range 0 to `Length-1`, would access `Arr[idx+Offset]`).  Unfortunately, if `foo` is a read-only instance of such a structure, current compiler versions won't allow operations like `foo[3]+=4;` because they have no way to determine whether such operations would attempt to write to fields of `foo`.

It's also possible to design a structure to behave a like a value type which holds a variable-sized collection (which will appear to be copied whenever the struct is) but the only way to make that work is to ensure that no object to which the struct holds a reference will ever be exposed to anything which might mutate it.  For example, one could have an array-like struct which holds a private array, and whose indexed "put" method creates a new array whose content is like that of the original except for one changed element.  Unfortunately, it can be somewhat difficult to make such structs perform efficiently.  While there are times that struct semantics can be convenient (e.g. being able to pass an array-like collection to a routine, with the caller and callee both knowing that outside code won't modify the collection, may be better than requiring both caller and callee to defensively copy any data they're given), the requirement that class references point to objects that will never be mutated is often a pretty severe constraint.

Answer (score 10):

Nah - I don't entirely agree with the rules. They are good guidelines to consider with performance and standardization, but not in light of the possibilities.

As you can see in the responses, there are a lot of creative ways to use them. So, these guidelines need to just be that, always for the sake of performance and efficiency.

In this case, I use classes to represent real world objects in their larger form, I use structs to represent smaller objects that have more exact uses. The way you said it, "a more cohesive whole." The keyword being cohesive. The classes will be more object oriented elements, while structs can have some of those characteristics, though on a smaller scale. IMO.

I use them a lot in Treeview and Listview tags where common static attributes can be accessed very quickly. I have always struggled to get this info another way. For example, in my database applications, I use a Treeview where I have Tables, SPs, Functions, or any other objects. I create and populate my struct, put it in the tag, pull it out, get the data of the selection and so forth. I wouldn't do this with a class!

I do try and keep them small, use them in single instance situations, and keep them from changing. It's prudent to be aware of memory, allocation, and performance. And testing is so necessary.

Comment: Structures may be sensibly used to represent lightweight immutable objects, or they may be sensibly used to represent fixed sets of related-but-independent variables (e.g. the coordinates of a point).  The advice on that page is good for structs which are designed to serve the former purpose, but is wrong for structs which are designed to serve the latter purpose.  My present thinking is that structs which have any private fields should generally meet the indicated description, but many structs should expose their entire state via public fields.

Comment: If the specification for a "3d point" type indicates that its entire state is exposed via readable members x, y, and z, and it's possible to create an instance with any combination of `double` values for those coordinates, such a spec would compel it to behave semantically identically to an exposed-field struct except for some details of multi-threaded behavior (the immutable class would be better in some cases, while the exposed-field struct would be better in others; a so-called "immutable" struct would be worse in every case).

Answer (score 9):

My rule is

1, Always use class;

2, If there is any performance issue, I try to change some class to struct depending on the rules which @IAbstract mentioned, and then do a test to see if these changes can improve performance.

Comment: A substantial usage case which Microsoft ignores is when one wants a variable of type `Foo` to encapsulate a fixed collection of independent values (e.g. coordinates of a point) which one will sometimes want to pass around as a group and sometimes want to change independently. I've not found any pattern for using classes which combines both purposes nearly as nicely as a simple exposed-field struct (which, being a fixed collection of independent variables, fits the bill perfectly).

Comment: @supercat: I think it's not entirely fair to blame Microsoft for that. The real issue here is that C# as an object-oriented language simply does not focus on plain record types that only expose data without much behavior. C# is not a multi-paradigm language to the same extent that e.g. C++ is. That being said, I *also* believe very few people program pure OOP, so perhaps C# is too idealistic a language. (I for one have recently begun exposing `public readonly` fields in my types, too, because creating read-only properties are simply too much work for practically no benefit.)

Comment: @stakx: There's no need for it to "focus" on such types; recognizing them for what they are would suffice. The biggest weakness with C# with regard to structs is its biggest problem in many other areas too: the language provides inadequate facilities for indicating when certain transformations are or are not appropriate, and the lack of such facilities drives unfortunate design decisions. For example, 99% of "mutable structs are evil" stems from the compiler's turning `MyListOfPoint[3].Offset(2,3);` into `var temp=MyListOfPoint[3]; temp.Offset(2,3);`, a transform which is bogus when applied...

Comment: ...to the `Offset` method. The proper way to prevent such bogus code shouldn't be make structs needlessly immutable, but instead to allow methods like `Offset` to be tagged with an attribute forbidding the aforementioned transform. Implicit numerical conversions too could have been much better if they could be tagged so as to be applicable only in cases where their invocation would be obvious. If overloads exist for `foo(float,float)` and `foo(double,double)`, I would posit that trying to use a `float` and a `double` often shouldn't apply an implicit conversion, but should instead be an error.

Comment: A direct assignment of a `double` value to a `float`, or passing it to a method which can take a `float` argument but not `double`, would almost always do what the programmer intended. By contrast, assigning `float` expression to `double` without an explicit typecast is often a mistake. The only time allowing implicit `double->float` conversion would cause problems would be when it would cause a less-than-ideal overload to be selected. I'd posit that the right way to prevent that shouldn't have been forbidding implcit double->float, but tagging overloads with attributes to disallow conversion.

Answer (score 9):

A class is a reference type. When an object of the class is created, the variable to which the object is assigned holds only a reference to that memory. When the object reference is assigned to a new variable, the new variable refers to the original object. Changes made through one variable are reflected in the other variable because they both refer to the same data.
A struct is a value type. When a struct is created, the variable to which the struct is assigned holds the struct's actual data. When the struct is assigned to a new variable, it is copied. The new variable and the original variable therefore contain two separate copies of the same data. Changes made to one copy do not affect the other copy.
In general, classes are used to model more complex behavior, or data that is intended to be modified after a class object is created. Structs are best suited for small data structures that contain primarily data that is not intended to be modified after the struct is created.

[Classes and Structs (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx)

Comment: Structures are also very good in cases where it's necessary to fasten a few related-but-independent variables together with duct tape (e.g. the coordinates of a point).  The MSDN guidelines are reasonable if one is trying to produce structures which behave like objects, but are far less appropriate when designing aggregates; some of them are almost precisely *wrong* in the latter situation.  For example, the greater the degree of independence of the variables encapsulated by a type, the greater the advantage of using an exposed-field structure rather than an immutable class.

Answer (score 6):

I was just dealing with Windows Communication Foundation [WCF] Named Pipe and I did notice that it does make sense to use Structs in order to ensure that exchange of data is of **value type** instead of **reference type**.

Answer (score 5):

Briefly, use struct if:

1. your object properties/fields do not need to be changed. I mean you just want to give them an initial value and then read them.
2. properties and fields in your object are value type and they are not so large.

If that's the case, you can take advantage of structs for a better performance and optimized memory allocation as they use only stacks rather than both stacks and heaps (in classes)

Answer (score 4):

The C# struct is a lightweight alternative to a class. It can do almost the same as a class, but it's less "expensive" to use a struct rather than a class. The reason for this is a bit technical, but to sum up, new instances of a class is placed on the heap, where newly instantiated structs are placed on the stack. Furthermore, you are not dealing with references to structs, like with classes, but instead you are working directly with the struct instance. This also means that when you pass a struct to a function, it is by value, instead of as a reference. There is more about this in the chapter about function parameters.

So, you should use structs when you wish to represent more simple data structures, and especially if you know that you will be instantiating lots of them. There are lots of examples in the .NET framework, where Microsoft has used structs instead of classes, for instance the Point, Rectangle and Color struct.

Answer (score 4):

Following are the rules defined at Microsoft website:

✔️ CONSIDER defining a struct instead of a class if instances of the type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in other objects.

❌ AVOID defining a struct unless the type has all of the following characteristics:

It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (int, double, etc.).

It has an instance size under 16 bytes.

It is immutable.

It will not have to be boxed frequently.

for further [reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: This answer seems to be just a repeat of (part of) [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6973171).

Answer (score 3):

I rarely use a struct for things. But that's just me. It depends whether I need the object to be nullable or not.

As stated in other answers, I use classes for real-world objects. I also have the mindset of structs are used for storing small amounts of data.

Answer (score 3):

Struct can be used to improve garbage collection performance.  While you usually don't have to worry about GC performance, there are scenarios where it can be a killer.  Like large caches in low latency applications.  See this post for an example:

http://00sharp.wordpress.com/2013/07/03/a-case-for-the-struct/

Answer (score 3):

Let me add another aspect besides the commonly cited performance difference and that is the intention revealing usage of default values.

> Do not use a struct if the default values of its fields do not represent a sensible default value of the modeled concept.

Eg.

- A Color or a Point makes sense even if all of their fields are set to their default values. RGB 0,0,0 is a perfectly good color and so is (0,0) as a Point in 2D.
- But an Address or a PersonName does not have a sensible default value. I mean can you make sense of a PersonName that has FirstName=null and LastName=null?

If you implement a concept with a class then you can enforce certain invariants, eg. that a person must have a first name and a last name. But with a struct it is always possible to create an instance with all of its fields set to their default values.

So when modeling a concept that has no sensible default value prefer a class. The users of your class will understand that null means that a PersonName is not specified but they will be confused if you hand them a PersonName struct instance with all of its properties set to null.

(Usual disclaimer: performance considerations may override this advice. If you have performance concerns always measure before deciding on a solution. Try [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html) it's awsome!)

Answer (score 1):

I think a good first approximation is "never".

I think a good second approximation is "never".

If you are desperate for perf, consider them, but then always measure.

Comment: I would disagree with that answer. Structs have a legitimate use in many scenarios. Here's an example - marshaling data cross processes in atomic manner.

Comment: You should edit your post and elaborate on your points - you've given your opinion, but you should back it up with why you take this opinion.

Comment: I think they need an equivalent of the Totin' Chip card (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totin%27_Chip) for using structs. Seriously.

Comment: How does a 87.5K person post an answer like this? Did he do it while he was a child?

Comment: @Rohit - it was six years ago; site standards were very different then. this is still a bad answer, though, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

✔️ CONSIDER Struct Usage

1. Create an object or don't need to create the object (directly you can assign values, it creates object)
2. Need Speed or performance improvement
3. No Need Constructors and Destractors (Static Contractor available)
4. No Need for class Inheritance, but Interfaces are acceptable
5. Small workload object work, If it goes high, memory issue will raise
6. You can't default values for variables.
7. Struct also available methods, event, static constructors, variable, etc
8. Less workload in GC
9. No need for reference types, only values type( every time you create a new object)
10. No Immutable Object (string is Immutable object because any operation don it returns any every time new string without changing the original)

Answer (score 0):

> Classes are best suited for grouping together complex actions and data
> that will change throughout a program; structs are a better choice for
> simple objects and data that will remain constant for the most part.
> Besides their uses, they are fundamentally different in one key
> area—that is, how they are passed or assigned between variables.
> Classes are reference types, meaning that they are passed by
> reference; structs are value types, meaning that they are passed by
> value.

- be careful using class. If you have some game objects that refer to the same memory, modifying one will modify the others.

> When a struct object is created, all of its data is stored in its
> corresponding variable with no references or connections to its memory
> location. This makes structs useful for creating objects that need to
> be copied quickly and efficiently, while still retaining their
> separate identities.

```
ExampleStruct struct1= new ExampleStruct()
ExampleStruct struct2= struct1
```

modifying `struct2` wont affect `struct1`.

- Basically, structs are created to increase performance. But, sometimes structs may be slower because of all the copying involved. If your struct has lots of variables that need to be copied converting it to a class and just passing references around may be faster
- If you have an `array of structs`, the array itself is an object on the heap and struct values are contained in the array. So `garbage collector` only has one object to consider. If the array goes out of the scope, the garbage collector can deallocate all the structs inside the array in one step. If any other part of your code is using structs from this array, since structs are copied we can safely deallocate the array itself and its contents.
- If you have an `array of objects`, the array itself and each object in the array are separe objects on the heap. Each object could be stored in a totally different part of the heap and another part of your code might have references to those objects. So when our array goes out of scope, we cannot deallocate the array right away. Because `the garbage collector` has to consider each object individually and make sure there are no references to each object before de-allocating them.

Answer (score -13):

Structures are in most ways like classes/objects. Structure can contain functions, members and can be inherited. But structures are in C# used just for **data holding**. Structures does **take less RAM** than classes and are **easier for garbage collector to collect**. But when you use functions in your structure, then compiler actually takes that structure very similarly as class/object, so if you want something with **functions, then use class/object**.

Comment: Structures can NOT be inherited, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taef578.aspx

Comment: Whether or not something is a struct has no bearing on how easy it is to be garbage collected.  That being said, under normal circumstances, a struct is not garbage collected *at all* - because it is not allocated on the heap.  However, just because its a struct does not mean it will *never* be allocated on the heap.  If its boxed, or if its a member of a reference type, then it will be allocated on the heap.  But once its allocated on the heap, it is handled by the garbage collector the exact same as any other reference type - it is no easier to garbage collect than any other type.