# Performance of struct containing a string vs class containing a string

Tags: c#, string, performance, cil

Please check out these two small examples:

```cs
public struct Struct
{
    public readonly string StringValue;
    public readonly int IntValue;

    public Struct(string stringValue)
    {
        this.StringValue = stringValue;
        this.IntValue = this.StringValue.GetHashCode(); // Just ignore this assignment, please :).
    }
}

public class Class
{
    public readonly string StringValue;
    public readonly int IntValue;

    public Class(string stringValue)
    {
        this.StringValue = stringValue;
        this.IntValue = this.StringValue.GetHashCode(); // Just ignore this assignment, please :).
    }
}
```

From what I know if I pass struct as a parameter it will make a copy of it `someObject.Method(this.cachedStruct);` - which in turn will make a copy of a `StringValue` as `string`s are immutable it will allocate array in memory for this string which is quite costly operation [pardon me if I made a mistake, please correct me in such a case].

So in this instance I assume it will be faster to use instances of the `Class` rather than copying `StringValue` each time. QUESTION: Are my assumptions correct and `Class` is a better choice for this kind of a situation or is it still more beneficial and faster to use `Struct`?

Since `String` and `string` are the same. ref - [What is the difference between String and string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-in-c).
I cannot use `String` in struct to prevent it from creating a new `string` object when struct has been passed as a parameter.

To better address the issue, here is another example. Sorry if it's a bit rough example.

```cs
public struct Struct
{
    public string StringValue;
    public int IntValue;

    public Struct(string stringValue)
    {
        this.StringValue = stringValue;
        this.IntValue = this.StringValue.GetHashCode(); // Just ignore this assignment, please :).
    }
}

public class Class
{
    public string StringValue;
    public int IntValue;

    private Struct _niceStruct;

    public void Accept(Struct someStruct)
    {
        someStruct.StringValue = "Something new"; // In this case even if I don't change the value, it was already allocated.
        // Because of copying of struct when it was passed as a parameter.

        Console.WriteLine(this._niceStruct.StringValue); // "Something new".
    }

    public Class(string stringValue)
    {
        this.StringValue = stringValue;
        this.IntValue = this.StringValue.GetHashCode(); // Just ignore this assignment, please :).

        this._niceStruct = new Struct("Old value");

        this.Accept(this._niceStruct);

        Console.WriteLine(this._niceStruct.StringValue); // "Old value".

        // String value was left unaffected.
        // Which [even in the case I wouldn't change the value in the method] means that a new `string` object was allocated when a copy of `Struct` was created.
        // When using `Class` in the same manner - it would change the `string`.
        // New `string` object won't be allocated if value is unchanged.

        // I assume that `string` allocation might be more costly than `Class` allocation in this instance.
    }
}
```

My understanding is that if I use `Struct` without changing `string` value it will still allocate memory for `StringValue` each time I pass it as a parameter. While when using `Class` and passing its instance as a parameter - it will pass `Class` instance as a reference type without copying values, thus not allocating any memory for `StringValue`.

My question might seem similar to [C#, struct vs class, faster? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484735/c-struct-vs-class-faster) and other questions (I believe I have gone through them all (the ones that struct vs class performance)) but none of them have given me an answer.

Comment: That is not how it works.  System.String is a reference type, you only copy the reference and not the string.  Very fast, references take 4 or 8 bytes.  Having two references to one string object is not a problem at all, given that it is immutable.  So you're fretting over a non-existing problem.

Comment: @HansPassant but in case `Struct` isn't immutable and I change `StringValue` after I have passed instance as a parameter, wouldn't changes only apply to one string, while the other would be left unaffected, retaining it's previous value?

Comment: You are changing the copy of the struct, not the string.  Otherwise the reason behind the common recommendation to never mutate a struct.  It is fine to do so, but programmers tend to have trouble reasoning through the consequences.

Comment: @HansPassant I have updated the question trying to better address the issue. Please, have a look at it.

Comment: It is as I said, the recommendation is to not mutate a struct.  But you're mutating a struct and are surprised that modifying the copy did not also modify the original.  Declare it as a class instead and it works the way you hope it did.  Or change the Accept() method parameter to `ref Struct` so it no longer operates on a copy.  Which is fine, but not efficient.  Structs were added to the C# language to make code faster.  They are a good match for the way a processor works.

Comment: @HansPassant I have an understanding between differences of reference and value types. I am not surprised that the value was changed. I want to understand if passing `struct` as a parameter is more costly than passing a `class` in case `struct` contains a `string` value. Does it mean if struct is immutable - compiler passes it as `ref` instead of copying it? Thus improving performance.

Comment: No, only using *ref* on the parameter declaration is inefficient.   Processors much prefer to work with copies and not references, they like a copy in their internal registers and hate to have to address slow memory through a reference.  There is no easy syntax to make a struct immutable.  You have to make the fields private and use properties that don't have a setter.  The C# language was designed to make things you shouldn't do harder to do.

Comment: @HansPassant now I understand what you have meant in the first comment. Sorry, I got confused and haven't understood `given that it is immutable` part right away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The string is for example at address **0x0110** and called **"hello"**. The struct does not store the string itself, it only stores the reference to this string. Thus the struct will only store **"0x0110"**. When you copy the struct, the struct copy will store the same reference **"0x0110"**. Not the string, just the reference. No new string object will be created. But when you change the string in the struct copy, for example from **"hello"** to **"bye"**, a new string will be created at a new address. For example **"bye"** will be at address **0x0220**. the struct copy will then store **"0x0220"** instead of **"0x0110"**. The original struct will still store **"0x0110"**. You are now having 2 strings in memory at different adresses.

**0x0110 "hello"

0x0220 "bye"**

PS: that is a simplification of what really happens.

Comment: `The original struct will still store "0x0220".` - did you mean `The original struct will still store "0x0110"`?

Comment: @CandidMoon_Max_ yes sorry. i fix it

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not know exactly how *reference* and *value* types work.

You have variable `a`of a type that is either class or a struct. This variable holds a *value*, thats all a variable is. What the value is depends one whether the type is a reference type or a value type:

- If its a reference type, the value of `a` is a *reference*, that is, a memory address where the referenced object is found.
- If its a value type, the value of `a` is the value type itself.

In C#, by default, variables are passed by value. That is, a *copy of the variable's value* is made:

```
SomeType a = new SomeType();
var b = a;
SomeMethod(b)

void SomeMethod(SomeType t) { }
```

`b` holds a *copy* of `a`. And `t` holds a copy of `b`.

If `SomeType` is a reference type (for example `string`) then all three variables `a`, `b` and `t` hold the same value; an address to the string instance originally assigned to `a`.

If `SomeType` is a value type, then all three variables hold three *identical but distinct* instances of the value type returned by `new SomeType()`. The variables that make up the inner state of said value type are themselves copied in the same manner: their *value* is copied.

Does that make it clearer?