# Realworld example of when struct can be used

Tags: struct

Can anyone provide a realworld example of when a struct can be used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A struct can be used when you have a complex return type for a method.  i.e. you have to return several values, and they don't really warrant a full class's overhead.

Answer (score 1):

A struct is notion of a record, a datatype that aggregates a fixed set of labelled objects, possibly of different types, into a single object. Structs are often used to group and relate objects in some manner.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a C struct, a great example is fixed scalar types in compilers. For example:

```
struct myScalar {
    void *payload;
    size_t psz;
    unsigned int refs;
    enum {
        S_STR,
        S_INT,
        S_FLOAT,
        S_OBJECT_INSTANCE
    }type;
};
```

Or a union could be used. Not a robust example, but you get the idea. You can then do

```
switch(aVar.type){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Structs are great for helping you parse data that has been compressed to bits for sending over "The wire".  You might have a bunch of bitfields to fill out a single byte, and a struct is a way to lay a template over this scrambled pile of variables and, without any real effort, change it into a collection of usable, easily referenced variables.