# C# Static class vs struct for predefined strings

Tags: c#, string, struct, static-classes

A co-worker just created the following construction in C# (the example code is simplified). His goal was to shorten the notation for all predefined strings in the rest of the code.

```
public struct PredefinedStrings
{
    public const string VeryLongName = "Very Long Name";
    public const string AnotherVeryLongName = "Another Very Long Name";
    public const string TheLastVeryLongName = "The Last Very Long Name";
}

public static void MethodThatUsesTheNames()
{
    Console.WriteLine(PredefinedStrings.VeryLongName);
    Console.WriteLine(PredefinedStrings.AnotherVeryLongName);
    Console.WriteLine(PredefinedStrings.TheLastVeryLongName);
}
```

Although it seems to work fine for him, I can't stop wondering whether he should have used a static class instead of a struct or if there's a more elegant way to achieve this.

What would be the preferred way to do this? Please also explain why.

Comment: Kudos to your co-worker!  My co-workers seldom use consts and we have string literals scattered throughout our code! lol

I do think, though, that the static class is sort of the standard.

Comment: I'm thinking about doing this as well but feel I am over-engineering things. I usually have a 2/3 strikes and refactor approach in that I scatter string literals initially then once I need that same string again in another method or class then I'll extract it into a static class.It can be a bit tedious though.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

With the `struct` solution, there's nothing to stop some other code doing `new PredefinedStrings()`, which won't *do anything bad*, but is something it's semantically confusing to allow. With a static class the compiler will forbid creation for you. And it goes without saying that static class is the preferred way of providing constants in the Framework.

*edit* to add, I said that second part without evidence - I have since searched and reasonably quickly found `System.Net.Mime.DispositionTypeNames` and `System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Http`.

Comment: That's probably the reason why the use of a struct made me frown at first, but I didn't think of checking the 'convention'. Thanks for the heads up. 
This answer is very useful for making the choice between the struct and static class and will probably sufficient to do the job.  However I'll have to check whether using resource files might be suitable here.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it seems suitable for this particular situation, since it is extremely unlikely the strings will change. Using the resource files is interesting but adds too much complexity to the current code at the moment.

Answer (score 32):

I would prefer the strings all being in a resource file and not embedded within the code - primarily for internationalisation reasons. This can then be accessed via a static class with the values as property members.

Comment: +1, this is the answer.  And not just for internationalization, but also that using a resource files allow you to correct errors or update your strings without re-building the whole app.

Comment: Funny I said the same thing earlier than this answer.. where are my upvotes?? :P

Comment: In this case, we're pretty sure the strings will not change, using resource files seems to be a bit of overkill for this particular situation. A static class will do the job (for now). However I'll keep this in mind for future use. Thanks!

Comment: You don't think they'll change.  Doesn't mean they won't.  Also, the second part is localization.  Do you think you'll never have to do that either?

Answer (score 27):

Besides a `static class` and `struct`, why not consider using `resource` files for constant strings? These can be accessed very easily as `SomeNamespace.ResourceName.KeyName`, and depending on where they are located in your project can be managed externally without recompiling if need be...

Comment: Check the timestamps and you were 1 minute later, but I'll give you +1 :)

Answer (score 14):

Simple rule of thumb: never use structs until you have no other choice.

Constants have a couple of drawbacks:

- only simple types can be used (strings, numerics, etc.)
- constants are injected into referencing assemblies. If you recompile assembly with constants and don't recompile assembly that uses constants, you'll get into trouble

I would write your code like this (notice rename refactoring too):

```
public static class KnownNames
{
    public static readonly string VeryLong = "Very Long Name";
    public static readonly string AnotherVeryLong = "Another Very Long Name";
    public static readonly string TheLastVeryLong = "The Last Very Long Name";
}
```

Comment: Care to explain why you use 'static readonly' instead of const?
Const would be evaluated compile-time, which is fine for the intended use.

Comment: I've listed const drawbacks: simple types only and compiled-in values. Use const if you are 100% sure it won't change (like Math.Pi, for example)

Comment: I get your point, thanks for elaborating. I don't expect the values to change, but you never know who decides to change the values in his endless wisdom ;-)

Comment: Attribute expressions must be constants, FYI.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing functionally wrong with this code.  But stylistically I agree a static class is better.  A static class declares the intent of the type is to only hold static / constant data.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're looking for a resource file (.resx).  It's a decent place to store such strings, and abstracting your strings into a .resx will make it easier to localize your application in the future.  The MSDN page at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ztca10y.aspx is a decent start for more information.

Answer (score 5):

ETA: Thank you to [Dennis19901](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9033739/dennis19901): since these strings are `const`, they will not actually take up any space. The `struct` will consume 1 byte only.

OLD AND BUSTED INFO: Don't forget the recommendation that a struct size should be about 16 bytes.  Given a 32-bit system, that's 4 System.String references right there.  I'd say you're better off with a static class if the number of strings will increase.

Comment: Good point. I remember having read that earlier, but didn't put it in practice for a long time, since most of my code doesn't seem suitable for structs :-)

Comment: This isn't relevant since they are constant strings. They are not included in the struct itself. The size of the struct in the code sample will simply be 1, since that is the minimum size. Static nor Constant members have anything to do with the size of a struct.

Answer (score 5):

static class seems to be the best way to go because it's the most standard and expected. I thought the struct/const versions might be faster but after some tests they were not.

Here are the results of my quick test that included length, compare, concat, copy, indexOf, and Substring. It was run under .Net 4.0 in release without a debugger attached.

```
                                          .Net 3.0  .Net 4.0
static class with static read-only string:  0.217   0.364  seconds
static class with const            string:  0.211   0.361  seconds
struct       with static read-only string:  0.211   0.372  seconds
struct       with const            string:  0.214   0.371  seconds
Properties.Resources               string:  1.173   1.268  seconds
```

They were all about the same performance except for when using a resource file, which is slower.  While Properties.Resources is slower, it is not stored in the executable so that can be more appropriate in some cases. So use either "static class" or Properties.Resources storing strings in my opinion.

Comment: Constant strings and static strings are handled the same way in memory. That's why the results are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Structs are normally avoided unless they meet certain criteria as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct).

Since your co-worker is not using it to store a value, he should be using a class, not a struct.

Answer (score 1):

I think static is better and here's my reasoning. If this code lives in some library, and another piece of code consumes this library, if the value of the constant fields change, then not only will this library need to be recompiled (duh) but you'll have to recompile the code consuming this library as well. The reason for that is, the compile inserts the constant values wherever you reference them. If you use static though, you won't have this problem, as you're referencing the *field* not the *value*.

Answer (score 0):

In my practice for this purpose we use `Dictionary<enumNameType, string>`. Where enumNameType is the different type of names you can have (in your case) ... This dictionary is wrapped in a static class and is cached - we create it just the first time we use it and then return the same object ...

I hope this will be useful for you, too!

Comment: What is the benefit of this over using constant values? With a dictionary you get fast lookup, yes, but not as fast as referencing a constant value directly.

Comment: @Dan The benefit is that we reuse the nomenclature in the enum type. We can used everywhere the semantic needs it and this enum type which represents a nomenclature is linked with a user friendly nomenclature in the dictionary.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about having an efficient way to get a string from an enum *that you're actually using as an enum*. I got the impression the OP is more concerned with cases where you just care about a constant string value; but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Dan Yeah you got it right. May be I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Dan is right about this. We're simply interested in fixed plain strings since they are 'forced upon us' otherwise we would have chosen enums in the first place :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use structs for constants too, but only for internal use, not for public APIs. It feels natural since enums are also converted to structs.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fact that you are allowed to create a new object that is intended to be a constant is clear evidence of bad practice (usually). I say "usually" because .NET does utilize the concept occasionally, though it is unclear why.

Of course, you can always do stuff like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public struct Bar
    {
        public static double A = 100;

        public Bar(double a)
        {
            A = a;
        }
    }
}
```

Which does technically justify the creation of `Bar`; however, there's no guarantee the constant `Bar` would ever be same (even in a single-threaded environment) and is ultimately of little use.