# In C#, use of value types vs. reference types

Tags: c#, class-design, value-type, reference-type

My questions are:

- When should we use value types and when reference types?
- What are the advantages and disadvantages of one over other?
- What if one uses reference types everywhere? Is there any harm in it?

Please also discuss advantages and disadvantages of each one. I want to understand that as well.

Comment: If you can't decide, it is almost certainly a `class`. It is incredibly rare to *legitimately* write a struct.

Comment: For Turkish programmers, I have a blog post about it http://sonergonul.net/2012/12/net-icerisinde-deger-tipi-ve-referans-tipi/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be a lot of confusion over this, and Jon Skeet does a good job of clearing it up in his book "C# In Depth, 2nd Ed." (section 2.3).

My personal approach, which may or may not be right, is to ONLY use structs/enumerations (value types) to represent lightweight, atomic data structures that I know I'll be using frequently in some kind of logical or mathematical operations - think `Point`, etc.

That way I figure I can avoid the garbage collection performance penalty. However, Jon points out in that section of his book that there's no real guarantee, especially in new versions of the runtime, whether something will go on the stack at all.

So my best answer is use things like structs sparingly and be very conscious about why you're using them if you do. Watch out for premature optimization. And read that section in Jon's book if you can get your hands on a copy, because he does a good job of clarifying this whole topic.

Related: [When to use struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c)

Answer (score 9):

You should use value types for small, **immutable** types which represent values.
[Never make mutable structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).

For everything else, use reference types.

Comment: your post doesn't explain why one should use value types?

Answer (score 7):

Use value types for immutables that do not have an identity of their own (a 1 is a 1), use reference types for other things.

Comment: Should strings have identities? :)

Comment: @Jon - special case... and one could argue that strings should have been implemented as value types. Would love to hear your take on it.

Comment: @Jon, considering that there's an internal string pool (indirectly accessible via `String.IsInterned`), one could argue that strings actually *do* have some special sort of identity.

Comment: @Oded and how much space on the stack would you reserve for a string **whose length you can't possibly know**?

Comment: @Oded: If they'd been implemented as value types, they'd have to have basically been references to something else anyway - after all, the size of a string won't be known at compile time. They'd effectively be reference types pretending to be value types. I guess they *could* have had the count in the value, with just a reference to the data itself, which could have been efficient in some situations...

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Whether some object ends up on the stack or on the heap (if there even is such a thing) is an implementation detail. Perhaps you're right, but this has nothing to do with the definition of what a value type is and what a reference type is.

Comment: @stakx: The point is that you *can* tell the difference between two equal but distinct string objects. So yes, they have their own identities... we just choose to ignore that most of the time :)

Comment: @Oded: please explain *why* one should use value types when he has the option of using reference types as well? What exactly is the difference? How am I going to decide?

Comment: @Oded - no, this isn't implementation details: fact; in .net the size of a struct must be known and constant (forgetting about the stack/heap - the IL **needs to know** the size); fact: structs have copy semantics (hence the issue having the same 50k lots of times just because of variables). These are both from the formal spec.

Comment: @Marc - I was just hoping to start a discussion... glad to see that I did ;)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

this is my reference on this point. I mainly use reference types tbh. IE classes and not structs. The main point that often gets said is that structs should only be used for small pieces of information. Really depends on the exact circumstances. Have a look at the .net framework in the object browser that should help, you will see what the microsoft guys have done and you can analyze why they made certain classes and structs.

Answer (score 1):

Immutable value types and immutable reference types are semantically all but identical; the only differences are that reference types support reference equality checks that may or may not be meaningful, and that value types may be wrapped in a Nullable(Of T) while reference types are implicitly nullable.  If a type is going to be immutable, depending how it will be used, there may be performance reasons to favor a struct or a class; structs are faster for some operations (nearly all operations, for sizes less than four bytes), while classes may bare faster for some others (especially for things larger than 16 bytes).  Further, some types of operations are essentially impossible with structs.

Mutable struct types are useful, contrary to what some naysayers claim, but there are some caveats.  If one has a variable that holds a reference to a mutable class object, and one does something to change that object, that change will effectively be "seen" by everything that holds a reference to that object.  If one wishes to change an object without disturbing anything else, one must know that one holds the only reference to that object.  Often times the only way to be sure of this is to copy all the data from the object into a new object instance, and then make the change to that new instance.  By contrast, if one has a mutable struct, one can simply make whatever changes one wants without having to create a new instance.

The only real problem with mutable structs is that .net uses various abstractions to make them behave as part of the unified type system, and these abstractions may cause copies of structures to be used in places where the originals logically should be used.  It's not always obvious when these substitutions may occur, and they can lead to confusing and erroneous behavior.