# When a struct is really useful?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C#, use of value types vs. reference types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739213/in-c-use-of-value-types-vs-reference-types)

I know the difference between `Struct` (Value-Type) and `Class` (Reference-Type).

But someone have a **Real** scenario where a `Struct` is really useful?

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c

Comment: +1: Good question. Outside of the predefined Microsoft ones, I see examples for complex numbers and micro-optimizations, neither of which I have much use for. Somebody give a real-world business case!

Comment: why the +1's - theres a few duplicates?