# How to set value type to null in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to set an int that is null, similar to how strings can be null. I've tried: int i = null; which returns `Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type` but string s = null; Is perfectly fine.

Comment: You need a nullable type.  i.e. `int?`

Comment: You'll have to use [`Nullable<int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.8) or simply `int? i = null;`

Comment: [Why do you want a null value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739213/)?

Comment: You should include the error rather than just saying "doesn't work".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So value types by default can't be set to null, there are however ways to get them to set to null. To solve your issue you would need to do this:
`int? i = null;`

This comes from the Microsoft docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/

Value Types versus Reference Types can be found here:
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type

Answer (score 1):

You can use question mark to make it nullable, like that:

```
int? x = null;
Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
```

This might help: [make nullable reference types in c#](https://www.codejourney.net/2019/02/csharp-8-nullable-reference-types/)

Comment: Would be good to mention that this is no longer a value type (or an `int`). Value types cannot be set to null.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `?` to the end of the type

```cs
int? nullInt = null;
if (nullInt == null) {
Console.WriteLine("nullInt is null");
}
```