# In C#, when should I use a struct and when should I use a class?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use struct in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c)

And conversely, when **shouldn't** I use either?

Comment: Glossing over the related questions, I see half a dozen potential dupes... too much choice!

Comment: This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx

Comment: Thanks for link.  I wanted a proper discussion on the merits of each.  The MS article just mentioned the words 'small', 'value', 'reference', 'complex' etc. without any quantification.  I wanted to discuss performance (e.g. what's the point where you get payback for using 1 over the over where you have thousands/millions of instances) and other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a class *unless you have a very specific reason to use a struct*. I realize it's a little bit trite, but it's true (trite and true! hah! right?)