# class and structure

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use struct in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c)

Why should we use class instead of structure

Comment: You got the information in that other Q&A, but just for clarity: the question should really be the other way around: *When should we use struct instead of class?*. Making a class should be your default option.

Comment: You should use a struct when your design calls for pass-by-value and a class when your design calls for pass-by-reference.  Yes, this is a useless answer, but it highlights the fact that there is no universally applicable rule, you have to make the decision in context of project-specific knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit broad but normally but Microsoft gives good answers, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hkbth2a(v=vs.80).aspx .

Comment: That article outlines techincal difference but does not really give any guidance on why to use one over the other.