# Reading from a sequential file into an array of structs

Tags: c#, arrays, file, struct

I have the following struct:

```
    public struct StudentDetails
    {
        public string unitCode; //eg CSC10208
        public string unitNumber; //unique identifier
        public string firstName; //first name
        public string lastName;// last or family name
        public int studentMark; //student mark
    }
```

Using that struct I wrote data into a sequential file. The data in the file is as follow:

```
ABC123
1
John
Doe
95
DCE433
3
Sherlock
Holmes
100
ASD768
5
Chuck
Norris
101
```

etc.

What's the best way to read the data from that file and load it into an array of structs?

Comment: are the strings a fixed size or variable?

Comment: @BrokenGlass: variable, because the first name and last name will vary in length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file is one value per line:

```
List<StudentDetails> studentList = new List<StudentDetails>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"filename"))
{

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        StudentDetails student;

        student.unitCode = sr.ReadLine();
        student.unitNumber = sr.ReadLine();
        student.firstName = sr.ReadLine();
        student.lastName = sr.ReadLine();
        student.studentMark = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());

        studentList.Add(student);
    }

    StudentDetail[] studentArray = studentList.ToArray();

}
```

Note that this is not very robust - if there are not 5 lines for each student, you'll run into problems, or if the last student has less than 5 lines.

**EDIT**

Taking the lessons learned  from your previous question [Array of structs in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050923/array-of-structs-in-c) regarding the need to override `ToString()` in your `struct`, the following might help to resolve your issue with printing the values:

In StudentDetails struct (taken from Nick Bradley's answer):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", unitCode,
           unitNumber, firstName, lastName, studentMark);
}
```

Then you could simply loop through the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Student #{0}:", i);
    Console.WriteLine(studentArray[i]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: The code works but the studentArray  doesn't print anything except  CA4.Program.StudentDetails, Any ideas?

Comment: Based on your previous question, it looks like you'll need to override the `ToString()` method in your struct. Can you post the code that's not performing properly?  See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Initially I'de use some sort of [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx) to write to the file since it will also take care of the reading part as well.
But given the way you created the file, I'de use [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) and it's ReadLine() method - since you know what the order of the properties you wrote to the server a simple while:

```
string line = "";
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  YourStruct t = new YourStruct();
  t.unitCode = line;
  t.unitNumber = reader.ReadLine();
  ...
  resultArray.Add(t);
}
reader.Close(); reader.Dispose();
```

Comment: The `(line = reader.ReadLine()) != null` condition in your while loop is going to throw that line away, as you don't do anything with it in the while loop.