# Does .Net create 1 stack(to store value types) for each dll and exe or 1 stack per program

Tags: c#, java, .net, memory-management

I am creating a service which will be consumed by presentation program. I am at a fork of defining my types as class or struct. Does .Net create 1 stack(to store value types) for each dll and exe or 1 stack per program. I am very sure it creates one Managed heap per program but not sure of stack. Please help me.

Thanks,
Omkar

Comment: Does it matter? This is an _implementation_ detail. You are assuming you know where reference types and value types will end up. See Eric Lippert's blog posts on [The Stack is An Implementation Detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx).

Comment: Yes it matters, if I need to pass structs from one function of one assembly to another, it will copy all values which is not good for performance...

Comment: Do you have some specific performance problem that you have identified as bottleneck for your application which is related to this *implementation detail* as perfectly qualified by Oded?

Comment: Before you optimize for such a scenario, make sure you actually have the problem. Did you measure performance and found out this is the issue?

Comment: No I am using class for now. I wanted to use struct but my manager told me there is separate stack each assembly. I could not find reference to his statement. So I am asking this question

Comment: As far as I know, there is a stack per _app domain_, not per assembly. Again, an implementation detail that should only matter if you are actually experiencing performance issues problems with it (which is unlikely).

Comment: @Omkarpanhalkar, you won't find a reference to this statement because this is an implementation detail.

Comment: @Oded - one stack per thread, not app domain.

Comment: got ya.. thanks... 1 stack per thread perfectly makes sense.. thanks guys..

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use struct in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c)

Comment: If copying local variables is too expensive, it's likely that they shouldn't have been structs in the first place. There are some exceptions in performance critical code, such as XNA, but generally only very small types should be a value type.

Comment: See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx).

As it happens there is 1 heap* per process and 1 stack per **thread** in a process, but you shouldn't care about this and certainly shouldn't use this when choosing between classes and structs.

See [When to use struct in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c)

(*) *Well, 1 managed heap anyway.*

Comment: The article The Stack Is An Implementation Detail is excellent, thank you @Justin!

Answer (score 2):

Since one call stack may contain calls from different assemblies and each thread has it's own stack trace obviously there is only one stack per thread.