# Which will consume more memory?

Tags: swift, class, struct

Suppose there are two arrays, one with *n* number of `Class` elements and one with *n* number of `Struct` elements. Which will consume more memory? Also what happens when we start manipulating the arrays. Below is what I tried.

```
class C {
    var a = ""
}

struct S {
    var a = ""
}


func sizeOf<T>(_ value: T) {
    print(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: value))
}

let classVar = C()
let structVar = S()

let arrayClass = [classVar, classVar, classVar]
var arrayStruct = [structVar, structVar, structVar]

sizeOf(classVar)
sizeOf(structVar)
sizeOf(arrayClass)
sizeOf(arrayStruct)

var newStruct = structVar
newStruct.a = "Value changed"

sizeOf(structVar)
arrayStruct.append(newStruct)
sizeOf(arrayStruct)
```

***Output***

```
8
16
8
8
16
8
```

Why is struct size greater than class and also why are both the array of the same size? Is it because array itself is a struct? Can someone provide with detailed explanation?

Comment: Why not allocate a million of each and find out?

Comment: @tadman I tried appending `10000` elements and the result was same. But it takes a lot of time in the playground to calculate that, allocating a million of each will take even longer.

Comment: That's at least one data point. It shouldn't take too long to allocate if compiled, mind you, so if that's an option try that. Does that list the total memory footprint of the object?

Comment: I ran each ```10_000_000``` times and the result was the same

Comment: I ran 10 million iterations with ```enum``` as well with the same result

Comment: Then maybe you have your answer, but it's worth checking the overall process memory footprint to see what differences there are. I'd expect `struct` and `class` to be effectively the same unless you have subclasses involved.

Comment: @tadman I just tested down 10 subclass layers, all with the same result.

Comment: @Jonathan If you've got data it's worth adding as an answer.

Comment: @tadman I noticed that recursive objects give larger numbers

Comment: Swift structs are generally dependent on the size of their components, in this case `String` has a size of 16 bytes so that is what you're seeing. Classes are generally pointer-sized as they are a reference to memory allocated somewhere. `Array`s themselves are laid out in such a way that they are fixed size no matter what they contain (I would assume that they are a pointer to some underlying implementation).

Comment: Is it ok to say that both the arrays will have same impact on the memory as arrays are structs and elements will be stored in their own memory space and array element will be a pointer to that particular memory?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related too: [Struct Memory Size vs. Class Memory Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975687/why-does-an-array-of-classes-consume-20-more-memory-than-array-of-structs?rq=1)

I ran the struct `10,000,000` times

I ran the class `10,000,000` times

I ran suclasses down to 10 layers `10,000,000` times each

I ran enum cases, and initialized enums `10,000,000` times

They all printed **8** (I will provide images)

---

I did find that doing this prints **16**

```
struct S { struct SS { var a = "" } }
SS() // 10,000,000 times
```

---

For both the struct and recursive struct, the actual memory size given by XCode was actually larger around 170MB, I just wanted to point that out.

all structs: ~170 MB <sub><sup>(even recursive ones)</sup></sub>

all classes: ~97 MB <sub><sup>(even subsclassed ones)</sup></sub>

all enums: ~20 MB

---

[image: Massive Subclasses]
[image: Basic Struct]
[image: Enum Case]
[image: Initialized Enum]
[image: Recursive Struct]