# Business logic class

Tags: c#

I have come across a few ways to write a business logic in asp.net but I am wondering for 2 example below, what are the benefits of using a struct to store class variables:

```
namespace Shopping
{
   public struct ShoppingCart
   {
       public string Color;
       public int ProductId;
   }

   public partial class MyShoppingCart 
   {

       public decimal GetTotal(string cartID)
       {
       }

       // Some other methods ...
   }
}
```

---

```
namespace Shopping
{
   public partial class MyShoppingCart 
   {
       public string Color{ get; set; }
       public int ProductId{ get; set; }

       public decimal GetTotal(string cartID)
       {
       }

       // Some other methods ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As dsimcha states in [their answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/521311/19679):

> Whenever you don't need polymorphism, want value semantics, and want
>   to avoid heap allocation and the associated garbage collection
>   overhead. The caveat, however, is that structs (arbitrarily large) are
>   more expensive to pass around than class references (usually one
>   machine word), so classes could end up being faster in practice.

As JoshBerke states in [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/521309/712603):

> Use a struct when you want value semantics as opposed to reference semantics.

From the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx

> **1.7 Structs**
>
> Like classes, structs are data structures that can contain data
>   members and function members, but unlike classes, structs are value
>   types and do not require heap allocation. A variable of a struct type
>   directly stores the data of the struct, whereas a variable of a class
>   type stores a reference to a dynamically allocated object. Struct
>   types do not support user-specified inheritance, and all struct types
>   implicitly inherit from type object.
>
> Structs are particularly useful for small data structures that have
>   value semantics. Complex numbers, points in a coordinate system, or
>   key-value pairs in a dictionary are all good examples of structs. The
>   use of structs rather than classes for small data structures can make
>   a large difference in the number of memory allocations an application
>   performs. For example, the following program creates and initializes
>   an array of 100 points. With Point implemented as a class, 101
>   separate objects are instantiated—one for the array and one each for
>   the 100 elements.

Comment: Plagiarism - the first paragraph is copied wholesale from  [When to use struct in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/521298)

Comment: Even with all of the edits, there is still no *original* material here whatsoever.

Comment: @Pekka LOL did you go through all this guy's recent posts checking for plagiarism?

Comment: @Aerovistae: See comments on [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160005/is-my-account-on-stack-overflow-locked) for context.