# Structs and Classes / value type vs refrence type

Tags: c#

So I've been trying to get my head around this for weeks.  I understand that structs are value types, and that classes are reference types.  Where I get confused is the differences in behavior between the two.

For example:
If I have a bag of potatoes, and each potato is a different size, shape, and weight...
The bag would be a 'class' / reference type
The potatoes would be a 'struct' / value type

Can my potatoes be a class, or do they have to be a struct as the values contained within are different?

Basically, the answer to that question will clear everything up for me.

Thank you!

Comment: I highly doubt an answer to the question "Can my potatoes be a class?" clears up anything.

Comment: Keep in mind the difference between a language-based value/reference type and a logical value/reference type.  A `class` may logically be a value type and internally maintains reference concepts like equality/immutability/etc.

Comment: Consider the kinds of things that are structs: `int`, `float`, `decimal`, `Color`; and the kinds of things that are classes: `Form`, `Page`, `StackPanel`, `Socket`.

Comment: This post explains very well when to use struct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c

Comment: The main difference is in "copy semantics" : What exactly happens with `a = b;` depends on rev or value type.

Comment: Okay.  I was, for some reason under the assumption that...
If potato was a 'class', that if i changed the weight of one potato, it would be reflected in all of them...

Comment: @user2455645 You're thinking of static vs. instance fields/methods. Has nothing to do with structs vs classes.

Comment: Okay.  Yeah.  I think that somewhere along the line in the past couple of weeks my brain just froze up... This all makes sense now.

Comment: Your analogy with potatoes will not help you at all

Comment: Elements (potatoes) that are contained inside some collection (bag) do *not* have to be of value type (struct). They could be of either value type or reference type (class). What made you think they had to be structs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all that you're tracking about potatoes is their size, weight and shape, then answer the question - "if two potatoes have the **same** size, weight and shape, should they be considered to be the same?". And the answer to that question depends on your problem domain.

If they should be "the same", then you're comparing them by *value* and (generally) could/should be value types. If they should not be treated as "the same", then they should be reference types.

Comment: I agree, although I think that the concept of identity is orthogonal to whether something is a reference or value type. I cite the example of the `string` class which is a reference type, but it behaves like a value type.  But you did say "generally", so I agree. :)

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't rely on discussing *comparing* since you can quite happily compare reference types by value...

Comment: Having "Identity" conflicts with Value types. Not having Identity (string) does not conflict with Reference type.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, that makes the question easier to answer. If something has "identity" then it *cannot* be a value type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take a `Potato` out of `BagOfPotatoes` and pass it around between other classes, if these classes were to modify the potato then it should be a reference type.

For example, `BagOfPotatoes` is passed to `Chef.SortPotatoes(List<Potatoes> potatoes)` and then goes on to `Chef.SkinPotatoes(Potato potato)` where the chef may skin the potato, setting `Potato.IsSkinned`.

- **If it were a reference type** - Then any values changed would also be changed in `BagOfPotatoes`. i.e. `Potato.IsSkinned = true`
- **If it were a value type** - Then `BagOfPotatoes` would still contain a bag with the original `Potato`s, i.e. `Potato.IsSkinned = false`

It deppends on whether or not you need to refer to a potato as an **individual potato**, where you chuck it about, and still talk about the same mashed up potato at the end of it (*by reference*). Or whether you only want to talk about the **type of potato** that it is (*by value*).

Comment: +1 for making the best of an awful analogy.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is a `struct` could be a `class` instead.  The two behave subtly differently, but your "potatoes" could certainly be a `class` instead of a `struct`.

Comment: I disagree, potatoes are inherently value types. I think you're confusing with tomatoes, which are definitely reference types.