# How to read struct items one by one in c#?

Tags: c#, list, struct, foreach

i have struct like this :

```
public struct GoldAverages
    {
        public decimal Sell_GoldOunce;
        public decimal Buy_GoldOunce;
        public decimal Sell_SilverOunce;
        public decimal Buy_SilverOunce;
        public int Sell_Mazene;
        public int Buy_Mazene;
        public int Sell_Gram_18;
        public int Buy_Gram_18;
        public int Sell_Gram_24;
        public int Buy_Gram_24;
    }
```

How can i read my struct items one by one (by name of item and value) and put them into Lable.text

like this

```
GoldAverages Gold = new GoldAverages();
foreach (var item in Gold)
        {
            LblSummery.Text += item.name + " : " + item.value + "|";
        }
```

Comment: why not use an array of key-value pairs or a dictionary instead? It looks like you are trying to solve the wrong problem

Comment: I want to now how can we access to struct childs one by one

Comment: Or perhaps read this [When to use struct in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: here i have few childs in my struct...but in other case my struct has 75 childs

Comment: "but in other case my struct has 75 childs" - Sounds like that is your problem there.  From your description, it sounds like you are thinking of a struct with many fields as being the same as a collection of many objects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
GoldAverage Gold = new GoldAverage();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var field in typeof(GoldAverage).GetFields())
    {
        sb.append(field.Name.ToString() + " : " + field.GetValue(Gold).ToString() + " | ");
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this (you'll need to add the `System.Reflection` namespace)

```
GoldAverages Gold = new GoldAverages();
Type gType = Gold.GetType();
IList<PropertyInfo> properties = new List<PropertyInfo>(gType.GetProperties());

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    string propertyName = property.Name;
    string propertyValue = property.GetValue(Gold, null);
    sb.Append(propertyName + " : " + propertyValue + " | ");
}

LblSummery.Text = sb.ToString();
```

And now that I look at your code again, you will need to update your fields to be properties, which I believe is what you are after. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: Or you could use `Type.GetFields`, no? And please use a `StringBuilder`!

Comment: Updated with StringBuilder. `GetFields` is an option, but properties are more typical when data is being accessed by other objects. I suggest the OP update those fields to properties.

Comment: GoldAverage Gold = new GoldAverage();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var field in typeof(Functions.GoldAverage).GetFields())
    {
        sb.append(field.Name.ToString() + " : " + field.GetValue(Gold).ToString() + " | ");