# Should i define a struct for the sole purpose of one function?

Tags: c#, performance, dynamic, struct

> I got a function that is in need of a custom data type, one way to
>   approach this problem is by defining a struct however this is only for
>   just one function, wouldn't it be better if i just use a dynamic
>   object instead?

**For example:**

```
public struct myDataType(){
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
}

public bool doSomething(string name, string email, string token){
    myDataType MDT = new myDataType();
    MDT.name = name;
    MDT.email = email;
    MDT.token = token;
    //Do something with MDT
    return 1;
}
```

***Or***

```
public bool doSomething(string name, string email, string token){
    dynamic MDT = new ExpandoObject();
    MDT.name = name;
    MDT.email = email;
    MDT.token = token;
    //Do something with MDT
    return 1;
}
```

**Note:**

1. > While i can define all possible props in the struct, i don't know how many i need to use.
2. > The Example is not real it just shows the 2 possible approaches.

Comment: Why are you so sure that you couldn't use the struct somewhere else? (you're using it already in two places since it's a return value)

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Second example won't compile and implies difference in how the function will be used.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, actually the struct must be used some where else because it's the return value. The code that calls the method will also use it.

Comment: @Euphoric that was just a typo fixed it, my bad :D.

Comment: Can you please explain where you got `Take the dolphins for a walk`

Comment: That would be true if i was returning it but in fact am not, my example shows that i return it but that's not the case so i'll re-edit my question.

Comment: @Jonesy a wild dream from my imagination, hope it comes true somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the purpose of `dynamic`. Dynamic is used when you don't know the type until runtime (and have a good reason to have such a scenario). Usages outside of this just de-value the strongly typed nature of C#, allowing code to compile that could be invalid at runtime.

If you need object A with properties B, C, D, then create that object, even if you are going to use it once. Besides, you will need to use that object when something calls your function and needs to access the properties of the returned object. It's better that those properties are known and strongly typed. You can use a struct instead of a class if you prefer, but make it a strongly typed object.

**Edit:** The original question was edited to indicate that the function does not return the object. Nonetheless, the above still otherwise holds true - that is, this is *not* a scenario when you don't know the type until runtime, and therefore it is *not* the right scenario to use `dynamic`. Since the usage of the object is short-lived, I would use a `struct`. See here for in-depth discussion on when `struct` should be used: [When to use struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: That's my case, because while i can define all possible props in the struct i may end just using 2 or three props max, so i really don't know how many props i need, that would qualify right?

Comment: I would say that it's hard to tell without seeing more about the context of what you are doing with the object. While I agree that defining a dozen properties just to use one or two of them doesn't seem to be the most practical way to go, I'm not convinced that `dynamic` necessarily is. For example, could one of the properties be a generic type? `struct Foo<T> { public T Property { get; set } }`. Your usage of this object would really affect the best way to structure it.

Comment: am retrieving some data, now the data is not always the same, for example i may get name & email but not token, ofcourse i don't have 3 params only i got about 8 params, so while i can use struct and have 8 params defined, that would not be so effective, my target is creating a list of the retieved objects & send them to client as a Json Array of objects, so what would you recommend in such case?

Comment: From what you described, I would question whether you need an object (dynamic or otherwise) to hold the properties at all. Why not just do what you need to do with each property without storing them in an object, if you are not doing anything object-specific with the object? It sounds like you can just build a JSON object that you need directly, without using an intermediary object (such as struct or dynamic as you have been debating) at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance impact if you choose any of the two solutions you came up with.

When the compiler meets the `dynamic` keyword it will do the same, will define a class that contains all the members defined.

for this example:

```
     new { Property1 = "something", Propert2 = "somethingElse" }
```

compiler will generate something like:

```
  class SomeNameChoosenByCompiler 
  {
         public string Property1 {get; set; } 

        public string Property2 {get; set; } 
   }
```

as you are actually using the object outside of your method i would go with the struct version as it makes the code more readable and easy to understand and maybe scalable in time.

Also, with `dynamic` you would loose compile-time benefits

Comment: But how about file size defining a struct would take more lines i guess.

Comment: yes there is a difference between anonymous & dynamic i know but how about the file size?

Comment: Are you asking about the file size of your *source code*?? Why would you possibly care?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either way.

My personal preference would be to use the strongly typed struct so that if I mistype any of the property names I'll find out when I compile the project.  If you use the expandoobject you won't find out until the code runs.

The other thing to consider is that a struct is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) while an expandoobject is obviously a reference type.  This may affect your decision because of the way the two types can be used in the rest of your code.  For example, a value type variable cannot be set to null, and they follow different copying semantics.

Answer (score 0):

A variable of a structure type is, in essence, a group of variables stuck together with duct tape.  A heap object of a structure type (i.e. a "boxed" struct instance) is processed by the runtime as though it were a class object with a variable of that structure type as its only field; any methods which would operate on the structure as a whole operate on that field, while those which would operate on the fields of the structure operate on its sub-fields.

The ability to binding groups of variables together with duct tape is useful if one will be using the variables as a group; almost all cases where one would want to do that, however, would require that the structure be used in at least two places (e.g. a place it's copied from, and a place it's copied to), though there are cases where all the places might be confined to a single function (e.g. one may have a variables `prevState` and `currentState`, each containing a few fields, and may want to be able to take a snapshot of all the variables in `currentState` and later revert all the variables to their earlier values).  Structures can be good for that.

I would suggest that it's often good to have very bare-bones structure definitions.  If one has a method which reads through a list and computes the minimum and maximum values according to some passed-in `IComparer<T>`, having a structure:

```
struct MinMaxResult<T> { public T Minimum, Maximum; }
```

could make things clearer than having a more complicated data type which wraps its fields in properties and tries to enforce invariants such as `Maximim >= Minimum`, etc.  The fact that `MinMaxResult` is a structure with exposed fields makes it clear that given the declaration `MinMaxResult mmr;`, code shouldn't expect `mmr.Minimum` to have any meaning beyond "the last value written to `mmr.Minimum`, or `default(T)` if nothing was written."  Everything of interest is going to be in whatever writes to `mmr`; the more concise definition of `MinMaxResult<T>`, the less it will distract from what's actually going on.