# Write back into list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list

I have a list of entries which is saved into database by following - shortened - code:

```
List<MyStruct> myStructList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<MyStruct>>(postdata);

foreach (MyStruct myStruct in myStructList) {
    if(myStruct.id==0) {
        // Not in DB -> insert.
        myStruct.id = (int)db.ExecuteScalar("INSERT INTO table ...");
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
// return all records with id set to auto-increment value.
return myStructList;
```

I want to return all records with updated id - but `myStruct.id` is not writeable, because of the foreach. So I replaced the foreach by a for loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<myStructList.Count;i++)   //foreach (MyStruct myStruct in myStructList), but writeable
{
    MyStruct myStruct = myStructList[i]
    if(myStruct.id==0) {
        // Not in DB -> insert.
        myStruct.id = (int)db.ExecuteScalar("INSERT INTO table ...");
    }
}
return myStructList;
```

but changing myStruct does not change myStructList.

Third try: Write back into the List.

```
for(int i=0;i<myStructList.Count;i++)   //foreach (MyStruct myStruct in myStructList), but writeable
{
    MyStruct myStruct = myStructList[i]
    if(myStruct.id==0) {
        // Not in DB -> insert.
        myStructList[i].id = (int)db.ExecuteScalar("INSERT INTO table ...");
    }
}
return myStructList;
```

which returns the error:

`Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyApp.MyStruct>.this[int]' because it is not a variable.`

So how on earth can I get this done?

Comment: you have a typo in `MyStruct myStruct = myStructList[i]`. It must end with a semi-colon `;`.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: Because the iterator variable is read-only, and `myStruct.id` is part of that variable, because `myStruct` is a value type.

Comment: When to use Struct

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c

Answer (score 6):

The problem is precisely because you've got a struct - and a mutable struct at that.

The indexer will return a *value* - if the compiler actually did let you change that value, it wouldn't modify the value that's already in the list.

Options:

- Fetch the value, modify it, then put it back in the list:

  ```
  MyStruct myStruct = myStructList[i]
  if (myStruct.id==0)
  {
      myStruct.id = (int)db.ExecuteScalar("INSERT INTO table ...");
      // Copy the modified value back into the list
      myStructList[i] = myStruct;
  }
  ```
- Change it to be a *class* instead of a struct, in which case your first approach will be fine.
- Make the struct immutable, but create a method that returns a *new* value which is the same as the old one, but with a new ID. Then you'd use:

  ```
  MyStruct myStruct = myStructList[i]
  if (myStruct.id==0)
  {
      myStructList[i] = myStruct.WithId((int)db.ExecuteScalar(...));
  }
  ```

(You could also create a *new* list of values instead of modifying the existing list, if you wanted.)

In general, [mutable structs are a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).

Comment: Vote for changing to class :)