# What does the class type constraint achieve if a generic type constraint must also implement an interface in c#

Tags: c#, generics

When writing generic methods and functions, I have seen the Where type constraint written as

```
public static void MyMethod<T>(params T[] newVals) where T : IMyInterface
```

and also

```
public static void MyMethod<T>(params T[] newVals) where T : class, IMyInterface
```

does the 'class' type constraint add anything - I don't imagine a struct could ever implement an interface, but i could be wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Yes structs `can` implement interfaces.

Comment: Yes, structs can implement interfaces. See : [Int32 Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `Enumerator` is an example of a struct that implements an interface. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `struct` can implement an interface, so it's quite reasonable to have the double constraint of requiring the generic type `T` to be both a `class` and to implement the specified interface.

Consider this from `Dictionary`:

```
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Enumerator : 
    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IDisposable, 
    IDictionaryEnumerator, IEnumerator
{
    //  use Reflector to see the code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Structs can implement interfaces. So this

```
where T : class, IMyInterface
```

demands both the type `T` be a `class` and a `class` which implements the interface called `IMyInterface`.

For instance this is the declaration of *Int32* structure:

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, 
                      IConvertible, IComparable<int>, IEquatable<int>
```

as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you - I would have marked you as answer (both answers with clear examples of where my assumption was wrong), but Dommer got in 1 min earlier

Comment: @Brent not a problem dude.