# using ref with struct c#

Tags: c#, .net, struct

i am writing a simple code by using ref keyword. As i understand struct can be really slow on copying things. In order to make it faster you should use ref. So i wrote this simple code below.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void returns(ref s s1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100;i++)
            {
                s1.z += i;
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            s s1 = new s();
            returns(ref s1);
        }
    }
}
```

it gave me the error "Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ref is less accessible than method". I checked one of stackoverflow question. Using ref seemed like that. What is my mistake here. Can you give me any advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This means that the type `s` is *not* public. It has nothing to do specifically with passing `struct` by reference.

Comment: "whenever you pass a struct as a parameter or assign a struct to another struct (as in A=B, where A and B are structs), the full contents of the struct are copied." The tuto i read meantioned about this.

Comment: @BeratEmreNebioglu That is correct. If that is a concern for your application .. then you should be using a `class`.

Comment: -1 for not including `struct s` in the question

Comment: i just learn c# i did java but dont remember i used "ref". @SimonWhitehead are you suggesting using class instead of using struct with ref. Also i heard for a group of variable that doesnt exceed 16bit  as sum like integer is 4 bytes. Four integer is 16 bytes. You should use struct. Do you agree with this?

Comment: By default, you should use `class` in c#. `struct`, while useful, has a number of gotchas and pitfalls that are not for beginners.

Comment: @crashmstr is there any source or link meantioned above "gotchas and pitfalls". I want to learn this language in real deep.

Comment: @BeratEmreNebioglu [Why are mutable structs evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil/441323#441323), [When to use struct in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c)

Comment: @crashmstr thank you very much i appreciated. So may be another subject but i need to ask String and String.textBilder String is immutable and textBuilder is mutable so we should choose string then. Because it is immutable?

Answer (score 2):

Likely the type `s` is not a public type.

Answer (score 0):

oh thanks i just forgot to type these lines to here.

```
public struct s
    {
        public int z;
    }
```

i did this private not i changed to a public. One of my friend suggest me to do private struct blah and do property of struct public. Is it false logic.

Comment: Your friend should have suggested to avoid `struct`s. And certainly mutable structs. Find a tutorial that starts with classes.

Comment: okey i am reading a good book i guess it is covering both subjects. Thanks for suggestions @HenkHolterman.