# Filling complex struct with two level array c#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I want to set values to my struct written en C# and i'm getting one error.

```
    private struct pack2
   {
      public float var;
      public float [3]var2;
   }
    private struct pack
   {
      public pack2[] ster;
   }

private void recv()
{
     pack mystruct;
     mystruct.ster = new pack2[4]; // Because I need to declare 4 structures of pack2
     mystruct.ster[0].var = 2F;
     mystruct.ster[0].var[0] = 1F; // error
}
```

ERROR : NullReferenceException was unhandled , Addinfo : object reference not set to an instance of an object

how can I fix it?

**SOLVED:**

```
private struct pack2
       {
          public float var;
          public float [3]var2;
       }
        private struct pack
       {
          public pack2[] ster;
       }

    private void recv()
    {
         pack mystruct;
         mystruct.ster = new pack2[4]; // Because I need to declare 4 structures of pack2
         mystruct.ster[0].var = 2F;
         mystruct.ster[0].var2 = new float[3]; // Because I need 3 floats on each pack2
         mystruct.ster[1].var2 = new float[3]; // Because I need 3 floats on each pack2
         mystruct.ster[2].var2 = new float[3]; // Because I need 3 floats on each pack2
         mystruct.ster[3].var2 = new float[3]; // Because I need 3 floats on each pack2
         mystruct.ster[0].var2[0] = 1F;
         mystruct.ster[0].var2[1] = 1F;
         mystruct.ster[0].var2[2] = 1F;
    }
```

I hope will be useful for people. Thanks to alex

Comment: Mutable structs are evil.  Those should be classes.

Comment: I want to echo what SLaks said, and provide this offical guidance from Microsoft: [Choosing Between Class and Struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the array.

```
// One instance
ster = new pack2[1];
```

You can find more information on Arrays [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx).

Structs are rarely useful in actual code. Most of the time you should be using classes.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6973171/1411687) on when to use structs (rarely).

Comment: It works thank u, how I should instance var 2 because i have the same error and i can't instance. thanks

Comment: The number in the square brackets determines the size of the array during creation. If you want to hold two instances of pack2 then you need to change it to `pack2[2]` etc.