# Confused about how C# struct work

Tags: c#, struct

I have a struct

```
public struct card
{
    PictureBox picture;
    double value;
}
```

I want to make an array of that, and Add/remove pictures and value as I go on. I'm not able to do this

```
card[] c = new card[13];
c[1].value = 4;
```

How do assign, read, and chance values of the those?

Comment: If you are just starting to learn programming with C# consider sticking with `class` for some time... If coming from C/C++ - `struct` is really close to what they are in C/C++ except not public buy default (with the same similar issues about default value semantics). In any case make sure to carefully read some of the discussions on [C# class vs. struct](https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+class+vs.+struct)...

Comment: Also see [When to use struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct)

Answer (score 6):

Make `value` [`public`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
public double value;
```

[By default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2%28VS.80%29.aspx), class/struct level elements are `private`, which makes it inaccessible.

It is recommended to capitalize public elements, and to use [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of fields, so using the following would be better:

```
public double Value { get; set; }
```

You may want to consider making your `struct` a `class`, as is not a very good fit. (See [When to use struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct), most of the time you will be working with classes in C#) You could also use a dictionary of picture's and their values:

`public Dictionary<Picture, double> Cards;`

Comment: I went with struct since I found them easy to use in C, also I'm not comfortable using class, and not clear on how to make one. Also could you elaborate on the  public Dictionary<Picture, double> Cards. Since That might be useful to me.

Comment: A dictionary is a collection that uses a key and a value (Also known as a HashMap in some languages) to store data. To make a class, you just change `struct` to `class`, and I would strongly recommend doing so. I use classes 99% of the time as structs are for very special cases.

Comment: So I'm trying to make a class, that contains a picture box and double value. However, i'm not able to able to make a variable of type "PictureBox" inside the class, any idea why?

Comment: If a struct is going to be used as a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape, rather than an object, it should *be* a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape.  Using autoproperties with classes leaves open the possibility that a later version of the class might do something different (e.g. lazily computing them, providing a change-notification mechanism, etc.) but since structs can't usefully do such things there's little advantage to using auto-properties.

Comment: @GK28 The difference between a `struct` and a `class` in C has almost nothing to do with the difference between a `struct` and a `class` in C#.  In C the difference is just the default accessibility of members.  In C# a `struct` has value semantics and a `class` has reference semantics, and both classes and structs have the same default accessibility modifiers on members.  You should be using a class here, not a struct.

Answer (score 1):

A struct in C# is not equivalent to a C struct. In C#, a struct has a *by value* copy semantic. This can be a bit confusing.

Consider the following:

```
Card[] cards = new Card[13];
Card card = cards[1];
card.Value = 42;
```

You would probably expect `cards[1].Value` to be 42, but you'll be surprised when you find out it isn't. This is partially the reason why [mutable structs are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).

Go with a `class` instead, which is closer to a C struct in the way that a copy of the reference to the class is passed, instead of copying the value itself:

```
public class Card
{
    public PictureBox Picture { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A structure is a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape.  If you want a bunch of independent-but-related variables stuck together with duct tape, it is often better to use a struct that exposes a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape than to design a class which tries to serve that purpose, or a struct which pretends to be an object of a class which tries to serve that purpose.  If, however, you want something that behaves as an object, then you should use a class.

Given `card` defined as shown, `card[] foo = new card[10]` will make `foo` identify an array holding ten references of type `PictureBox` and ten `double` values.  The declaration `card bar;` will define space for another `PictureBox` reference and another `double` which are independent of anything else in the universe.  Saying `bar = foo[3];` will be equivalent to `bar.picture = foo[3].picture; bar.value = foo[3].value;`, and will not establish any lasting relationship between the fields of `bar` and those of `foo[3]`.

Duct-taped-variable structures can be very useful for some purposes, such as holding the coordinates of a point, but it is important to recognize them for what they are.  If you want a type to represent an object, use a class.  Only if you want it to hold a bunch of independent but related variables duct-taped together should you use a `struct`.