# Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructor

Tags: c#

**Hi,**

I am getting "Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructor" error during build but i am able to compile the program with errors.

```
struct Program
{
    string Name;
    string Degree;
    string Dpthead;
    //Constructor
    public Program ()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter the Program's Name: ");
       Name = Console.ReadLine();
       Console.WriteLine("Enter the Program's Degree Name: ");
       Degree = Console.ReadLine();
       Console.WriteLine("Enter the Head of Program : ");
       Dpthead = Console.ReadLine();
     }
     public void PrintUProgramDetails()
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Program Name: {0} from {1}. Enrolled in {2} degree(s)", Name, Degree, Dpthead);
     }

}
```

What are the possible ways to correct this error? Any help or guidance.

Comment: *C# 6.0's* structure will be able explicit *parameterless constructor*

Comment: _"What are the possible ways to correct this error?"_ Either use a class or don't use the constructor.

Comment: You should not use a struct for a program, Structs are immutable data-objects.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Structs are not immuatable. A good design makes them immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `struct Program` a `class`.

`structs` are immutable data-objects. There are plenty of recommendations [when to use structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct):

> **Consider defining a structure instead of a class if instances of the type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in other objects.**
>
> Do not define a structure unless the type has all of the following characteristics:
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (integer, double, and so on).
> - It has an instance size smaller than 16 bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.

Secondarily, the `Program`-constructor you have there would be better considered as `main`-method. Then call the constructor of your data-object with the three `string`-values as parameters.