# Storing named structs in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, struct

I have a struct like this.

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public string name;
    // other variables and stuff

    public MyStruct(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I'm storing many, possibly hundreds or even thousands of those in a dictionary with their `name`s as keys.

```
var myStructs = new Dictionary<string, MyStruct>();
myStructs.Add("Foo", new MyStruct("Foo"));
```

I don't always have access to the dictionary's keys (such as when retrieving values) so the names of the structs have to be defined in them.

My problem is, the structs can have different names than their keys in the dictionary. Is it an actual problem to have such a condition exist?

```
myStructs.Add("Bar", new MyStruct("Baz"));
```

This is a bit of off-topic on this question yet kind-of relevant to the problem above, but if the name of a struct under the key `Foo` is changed, how would I update the key to the new name?

```
var temp = myStructs["Foo"];
temp.name = "Bar";
myStructs["Foo"] = temp;
```

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct

Comment: @Blorgbeard So I should rather use a class than a struct? Got it.

Comment: yes, almost certainly. Your default choice should be class, for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a unique `ID` and a `DisplayName` in `MySctuct`. If you save records in a database having a unique would be a better option. And actually a `List<MyStruct>` will provide you the same functionality in this case and you don't have to bother about changing the `Dictionary` `key`.

As per MSDN, you should use a Class in your case.

[Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx)

**√ CONSIDER** defining a struct instead of a class if instances of the type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in other objects.

**X AVOID** defining a struct unless the type has **all** of the following characteristics:

- It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types
  (int, double, etc.).
- It has an instance size under 16 bytes.
- It is immutable.
- It will not have to be boxed frequently.

Comment: I'll go with a list and some LINQ magic to find the values based on a given name. Also, Microsoft itself is violating the guidelines they've set. Not that I mean to completely ignore them, I just don't feel like forcing myself to follow them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = myStructs["Foo"];
myStructs.Remove(temp.name);
temp.name = "Bar";
myStructs.Add(temp.name, temp);
```

Alternatively, you can make `MyStruct.name` into a property, and automatically update whenever the `name` changes:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    private string _name;
    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        { 
            if (_name == value) return;
            GlobalStorageClass.myStructs.Remove(_name);
            _name = value;
            GlobalStorageClass.myStructs.Add(_name, this);
        }
    }

    public MyStruct(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        GlobalStorageClass.myStructs.Add(name, this);
    }
}
```

Where `GlobalStorageClass.myStructs` is the dictionary.

Comment: Ugh, global arrays, properties and constructors with weird side-effects.. Yuck.