# Why does a C# linked list class variable not retain its value after it's assigned?

Tags: c#, variables, methods, linked-list, assign

I am creating a crossword puzzle generator and seem to have an issue with a simple variable assignment of co-ordinates in the grid system.
I have a very simple structure to hold discrete coordinate values as seen below. I have stripped encapsulation to make it easier to read.

```
    public struct vec2
    {
        public int x, y;
        public vec2(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
```

This Vec2 Structure is maintained inside a class to hold word values

```
public struct WordClass
{
    string svalue;
    bool flag;
    public vec2 position;

    public WordClass(string sarg, bool barg)
    {
        this.svalue = sarg;
        this.flag = barg;
        position = new vec2(0,0);
    }
    public string StringVal
    {
        get { return svalue; }
    }
    public bool FlagVal
    {
        get { return flag; }
    }
    public void DisableWord()
    {
        if (this.flipflop == false)
        {
            this.flipflop = true;
        }
    }
    public void SetPos(int xa, int ya)
    {
        this.position.x = xa;
        this.position.y = ya;
    }
}
```

This should basically maintain a list of permanent words with a flag for usage, and a variable position as the system calculates optimal locations for the word.

I have a dynamic linked list of words

```
    List<WordClass> WordList = new List<WordClass>();
```

and to change the coordinates of a word in the wordlist

```
    //Arbitrary values
    WordList[0].SetPos(Position_X, Position_Y);
```

Now my issue is that when I try to use the position of the word, no matter what I set it too prior, it maintains a default value of 0, 0. I have been scratching my head while doing other functionality, and it's left me wondering if I'm missing something important.

Comment: Check out ["When to use struct?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/521298/382780). Your structs are mutable, which can cause problems like this where you try to set a value but it doesn't appear to "stick" because you're actually changing the value on a copy of the struct. I don't think you should use structs here.

Comment: Cheers for the link, I'm still an amateur programmer and I thought Classes and Structs were fully interchangeable in c#. This seems to have mostly solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be related to the fact that `vec2` is a `ValueObject` and you're trying to change it. The problematic lines are concretely those two:

```
this.position.x = xa;
this.position.y = ya;
```

Why? Because `vec2` is a a `struct` each time you read it you get a **temporary copy**, then modify that copy, then the copy is thrown away, while you're still reading the original, unmodified one. That's one reason why value objects should be **immutable** as much as possible, unless you've got a strong reason.

The first step should be to make a proper immutable `vec2` structure:

```
public struct vec2
{
    public int x { get; private set; }
    public int y { get; private set; }

    public vec2(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Once you've got that, you need to take care of the modification in the `SetPos` method. Since the structure is immutable you can no longer read it, but instead each time you need to change it you'll throw the current instance away and create a new one:

```
public void SetPos(int xa, int ya)
{
    this.position = new vec2(xa, ya);
}
```

This creates a brand-new structure and assings it to the internal field, containing the new values. As this doesn't really attempts to modify the structure, but instead change the structure for a new one it won't be subject to the same subtle bug.

Comment: _`vec2` is a a struct each time you read it you get a temporary copy_ Are you sure that it is happening in _that concrete case_? Note that we have `List<WordClass>`, and `WordClass` is `struct` as well.

Comment: Cheers for this, Paired with the comment made on my question by @31eee384 its fully solved my issue. It was to do with temporary copies and structs.

Comment: @AlexD That will just exacerbate the problem, so the temp copy problem might happen *twice* instead. I haven't checked as carefully as it should, but still the problem with mutable structs is there. That said, when I have a compiler handy I will test :D

Comment: @Alejandro If we access the field `position` as in the given code, no copy of the struct should be created.