# Why is .NET's Version a class and not a struct?

Tags: c#, .net, struct

According to [ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/version.cs), the `Version` class is `sealed`, `ICloneable`, `IComparable`, `IComparable<Version>`, `IEquatable<Version>`. It also only stores `int` values. Is there a particular reason why the .NET programmers chose to make this a class instead of a struct? Why would someone need a `null` version?

Here's the field declaration block from ReferenceSource:

```
// AssemblyName depends on the order staying the same
private int _Major;
private int _Minor;
private int _Build = -1;
private int _Revision = -1;
```

They even make a comment, saying they need to keep the fields aligned. Maybe it's just me, but this is really a struct thing?

Comment: The difference between a `struct` and a `class` is more than simply allowing a `null` value...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The OP clearly knows this, hence all the details mentioned in the question, which are indeed intended to make this class behave mostly like a value.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know, but that's the only use I could think of it as a class instead of a struct...

Comment: @KonradRudolph that's basically it. I feel it should behave like a value...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why would someone need a `null` version?

To specify that no version is specified, for instance in `AssemblyName` as referred to in the comment in your question. An `AssemblyName` may omit the version when passed to `Assembly.Load`, for instance, in which case its `Version` property will be `null`. Remember that these types were created for .NET 1.0, which didn't have generics, so `Nullable<Version>` didn't exist yet as an alternative.