# Are options types good candidates for structs?

Tags: c#, struct

Please consider the following immutable type:

```
public class/struct AServiceOptions {

    public AServiceOptions (Uri baseAddress, int workersCount, TimeSpan maxIdleTime) {
        BaseAddress = baseAddress;
        WorkersCount = workersCount;
        MaxIdleTime = maxIdleTime;
    }

    public Uri BaseAddress { get; }
    public int WorkersCount { get; }
    public TimeSpan MaxIdleTime { get; }
}
```

Used in the following manner:

```
public class AService {

    public AService (AServiceOptions options) {
        Options = options;
        Initialize();
    }

    AServiceOptions Options { get; }

    private void Initialize () {
        InitHttpClient(Options.BaseAddress);
        InitWorkers(Options.WorkersCount);
        InitTimer(Options.MaxIdleTime);
    }

    // Service implementation details
}
```

Is the `AServiceOptions` type a good candidate for a Struct? Why / Why not?

Answer (score 1):

No, because this kind of type instances are suitable for being shared during a call stack, and you know that structs are values so you're not sharing the same object when passing it as argument on methods **but you're creating copies**, unless you use the `ref` keyword.

In summary, it should be a *class*.

See this other Q&A to get further details about when to use structs: [When to use struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good candidate for a `struct`, because all your `AService` objects would be limited to using the same options implementation, without a possibility to inherit for subclass-specific options.

This is not possible with a `struct`:

```
public struct AServiceOptions {
}
public struct ADerivedServiceOptions : AServiceOptions { // Not possible
}
public class AService {
    public AService(AServiceOptions opt) ...
}
public class ADerivedService {
    public ADerivedService (ADerivedServiceOptions opt) ...
}
```

In addition, `struct` does not "buy" you anything: an immutable class would be just as good, and it would also avoid boxing/unboxing if you need to pass options as an `object`.

Answer (score 0):

I've designed and implemented an option system. I think the best way to approach this problem is to have a base class 'Option'. My argument on why it should be a class is because the options of most applications tend to grow with time. ( if you are extending the modules, writing new code etc..)