# All of my custom class (item) references are giving me the actual item in database and not a duplicate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a database script that holds a list of many items that I created through custom classes. Item is the base class and equipment inherits from item class. I fill my players inventory from pulling from this database of items as such:

```
[SerializeField] private List<Equipment> equipment = new List<Equipment>();

public Item GetEquipment(int id)
{
    return equipment[id];
}
```

All was well until I added a way for the player to upgrade the level and stats of an equipment item. I had 2 of the same swords given to the players inventory at runtime as such:

```
private void Awake()
{
    // just adding items for testing
    db = GameManager.i.GetDatabase();

    // give two swords
    items.Add(db.GetPrimaryWeapon(0));
    items.Add(db.GetPrimaryWeapon(0));
}
```

If I level one up, the other levels with it, even though I did not spend the currency or even click on the other sword!

I have found that it is leveling the (itemLevel) attribute in the actual database.

How am I supposed to pull unique copies of my custom class from my database? The goal is like all games with items that can be upgraded.
I want the player to be able to individually level up a sword even if he has many of the same duplicate swords in his inventory.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you assume `GetPrimaryWeapon(0)` returns two different instances if you just call it twice? Ofcourse it will just give the exact same item from your database, when you provide the exact same id. Why do your items even *have* the same ids in the first place when they are actually different things?

Comment: I assumed because i have never been taught....
I am not calling the same id but index of the list that holds the equipment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well assuming your `Equipment` is indeed a `class` it is always just passed as a **reference** - both returned references of `db.GetPrimaryWeapon(0)` point to the **exact same memory location** - aka to the **exact same instance** of your class (-> [Reference Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types))!

> How am I supposed to pull unique copies of my custom class from my database

One (lazy) way would be to use a `struct` so it would become a [Value Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) instead and simply be passed by value so always as a copy - in most cases this not the way to go though -> [When should I use a struct rather than a class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-should-i-use-a-struct-rather-than-a-class-in-c)

Or instead rather implement this mechanic into your type.

For instance you could have a dedicated constructor which creates a copy of the instance

```
public class Equipment 
{
    public Equipment(Equipment origin)
    {
       // whatever fields etc need to be populated with the same values
    }
}
```

and in there do whatever is required to crate an exact copy of all members within this instance. Also see [Deep Cloning Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects) in case of more complex data structures.

And then you would always rather return a clone from the "database"

```
public Equipment GetEquipment(int id)
{
    return new Equipment(equipment[id]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this was the problem. I didn't realize i was passing as a "reference" and not a clone.  Thanks for helping me become better!