# When should Structs be used in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, struct

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When to use struct in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c)
>   [When should I use a struct instead of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class)

What would be some instances when one would want to use Structs in C#?

Is it when you want a lightweight, immutable class?  How will the stack vs heap allocation effect me and what should I be aware of? Are there any other instances of when it would make sense to use structs?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c

Comment: Thanks, the second link was helpful. "When should I use struct instead of a class?" one.