# How send and receive struct type variable in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, struct

I have this code in my WCF server:

```cs
public struct Detail
{
    public String ID;
    public String Event;
    public String Date;
    public String Title;
    public String Content;
    public String Type;

}


public class Service1 : IService1
{

    LINQDataContext LINQ = new LINQDataContext();

    public Detail[] AllNews()
    {
        var ResultLoad = LINQ.Show_All().ToList();
        int count = ResultLoad.Count();
        Detail[] News = new Detail[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            News[i].ID = ResultLoad[i].Id.ToString();
            News[i].Event = ResultLoad[i].Event;
            News[i].Date = ResultLoad[i].Date;
            News[i].Title = ResultLoad[i].Title;
            News[i].Content = ResultLoad[i].Content;
            News[i].Type = ResultLoad[i].Type;
        }
        return News;
    }

}
```

I want to receive News data in my Client app. I use this code, but it doesn't work:

```cs
ServiceReference1.Service1Client Client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        Detail[] MainNews = new Detail[1000];

        MainNews = Client.AllNews;
```

How can I receive News data from WCF in main client app?

Comment: what is the response for Client.AllNews()?

Comment: "i use this code, but not work" - Well, what is not working? What's happening. "Not working" is very broad!

Comment: it mean i cant access to News data from WCF server file, how can i access to that?

Comment: Closing this because no useful error description is present and none has been added after having been asked for it. Unanswerable.

Comment: 1. [Do not use a struct.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1772274/648075) 2. You're using WCF and yet there's not a single `DataContract` to be seen in your code.

Comment: this post might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772197/using-structs-with-wcf-services?rq=1