# C#: Are struct members more performant?

Tags: c#, performance, class, struct

On a [blog entry, Luca Bolognese](http://blogs.msdn.com/lucabol/archive/2008/04/21/a-c-library-to-write-functional-code-part-iii-records.aspx) ponders this idea about structs vs. classes as member fields:

> The reason to use a struct is to not
>   allocate an additional object on the
>   stack. This allows this solution to be
>   as 'performant' as simply having coded
>   the fields on the class itself. Or at
>   least I think so ...

How accurate is this?

First, doesn't he mean allocate an additional object on the **heap**?

And, wouldn't using structs marginally decrease allocation time (especially if the class members were lazy-loaded) at the expense of increasing the memory footprint?

Would you recommend this practice of structs over classes in certain situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think he did mean to write heap, he just wrote stack by mistake.

The question of structs or classes comes up quite often. Here's one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class). I think it's best to follow this commonly given advice:

---

MSDN has the answer: [Choosing Between Classes and Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx).

Basically, that page gives you a 4-item checklist and says to use a class unless your type meets all of the criteria.

Do not define a structure unless the type has all of the following characteristics:

```
* It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (integer, double, and so on).
* It has an instance size smaller than 16 bytes.
* It is immutable.
* It will not have to be boxed frequently.
```

---

Are there times you shouldn't follow this advice? Maybe, but only after you've proved it by profiling.

Comment: Thanks Mark - so, to extend on the last item in that list: if I need to use/pass a class's field often (thus unboxing it) the field should not be a struct, yes?

Comment: @JeffMeatballYang: Value types are boxed when, and only when, they are copied to storage locations (variables, parameters, fields, etc.) of reference types (e.g. `Object`, `ValueType`, or any interface type).  If one stores a `Rectangle` in a `List<Rectangle>`, there will be no boxing.  If one stores a `Rectangle` in a `List`, however, there will be boxing, since the latter will require storing each `Rectangle` in a location of type `Object`.  While there are a few cases where boxing will be unavoidable, in general if you're boxing value types, you're doing something wrong.