# Class + Struct is a good coding style?

Tags: c#

I am reading existing code. I noticed that there are many data object files which have a struct and a class together to define a data object. Like the following one: do you think it is a good style?

```
In ONE file:

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct LaneDataStruct
    {
        public ushort red;
        public ushort yellow;
        public ushort green;
        public ushort blue;
        public ushort orange;
    }

public class LaneData
    {
        private LaneDataStruct laneDataStruct;
    public LaneData(ushort red, ushort yellow, ushort green, ushort blue, ushort orange)
    {
        this.laneDataStruct.red = red;
        this.laneDataStruct.yellow = yellow;
        this.laneDataStruct.green = green;
        this.laneDataStruct.blue = blue;
        this.laneDataStruct.orange = orange;
    }

    public LaneData(ushort[] values)
    {
        this.laneDataStruct.red = values[0];
        this.laneDataStruct.yellow = values[1];
        this.laneDataStruct.green = values[2];
        this.laneDataStruct.blue = values[3];
        this.laneDataStruct.orange = values[4];
    }

    public LaneData(LaneDataStruct laneDataStruct)
    {
        this.laneDataStruct = laneDataStruct;
    }

    public LaneDataStruct getLaneDataStruct()
    {
        return this.laneDataStruct;
    }

    public string toString()
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append("LaneData.red=" + this.getLaneDataStruct().red + "\n");
        stringBuilder.Append("LaneData.yellow=" + this.getLaneDataStruct().yellow + "\n");
        stringBuilder.Append("LaneData.green=" + this.getLaneDataStruct().green + "\n");
        stringBuilder.Append("LaneData.blue=" + this.getLaneDataStruct().blue + "\n");
        stringBuilder.Append("LaneData.orange=" + this.getLaneDataStruct().orange);

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: While you're not referring to this, I think it *is* bad style to add a public `toString()` method when you should actually override `ToString()`, and also using a string builder, but then concatenating strings instead of using `AppendFormat()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only call this a good practice in an exotic P/Invoke scenario, and even then it's questionable.

First, the struct is poorly designed since it is mutable.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class/85656) for more information.

The class looks like it was written to address the fact that in C#, there is no deterministic way to initialize a structure.  You can't give a struct a default constructor, and you can't cause a non-default constructor to be called.  So it looks like the class wraps the structure and gives a guarantee that the structure will be initialized to some state.  However, it does no validation so I strongly doubt there is any value to it at all.

This would only be "useful" if `LaneDataStruct` represents a structure that is used for P/Invoke (the LayoutKind attribute is a hint this may be true) and that can't have certain values.  It would still be preferable to give it properties that perform validation and make the fields private.  Usually, P/Invoke code is written in a separate layer where it's considered acceptable to have warts like "make sure to initialize this struct after creating one".

Comment: P/Invoke is the name of the mechanism .NET uses to call functions in Windows DLLs.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that it's a mutable struct with public fields is bad style to start with.

I can't say I've seen it used, and I wouldn't want to really.

Comment: I use mutable structs for low-level communication with bus systems or embedded hardware all the time, because it's the most exact translation from typical embedded header files (with all that MarshalAs and StructLayout stuff). I guess you *could* use classes for that, but I don't see the point. For code in general, of course, I agree with you, but I think there *is* an area where they can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Structs in C# are POD types -- with slightly different semantics. MSDN [says this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4(VS.71).aspx):

> The struct type is suitable for
>   representing lightweight objects such
>   as Point, Rectangle, and Color.
>   Although it is possible to represent a
>   point as a class, a struct is more
>   efficient in some scenarios.

Even if this distinction wasn't there (C++) it is good practise to differentiate POD types using a seperate keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I would use a Struct in this manner, especially with a StructLayout Attribute is if I were doing PInvoke to a 3rd party or legacy C DLL, where I had to pass this structure to be marshalled, or if I were doing some sort of serial communications protocol over the wire where I wanted my structure to exactly match the packet I was sending/receiving.