# creating a byte array member for a structure in C#

Tags: c#, structure

I have a structure definition as follows:

```
public struct check
{
    public int[] x = new int[3]; //error
}
```

This is an error because you cant define an array size for a structure member in C#. I cant define the space for this array even in a default constructor in C# because parameterless constructors aren't allowed.

How do I do it? I know structures are immutable in C#.

I am using this structure not to create new objects but just to typecast objects of other class types.

```
check corp = (check )WmUtils.WM_GetObj(Attr);
```

Wm_getObj returns an object of check2 class type. Is readonly keyword helpful here?

Comment: Structures are *not* innately immutable in C#. It's just a really bad idea to have them be mutable, as it can lead to all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a parameter less constructor and you can't define an array with size in struct, this leaves you with a structure constructor taking a `size` as parameter like:

```
public struct check
{
    public int[] x;
    public check(int size)
    {
        x = new int[size];
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for sure I know but I dont want a size to be passed when creating the object because the size is always fixed as 3.

Comment: If the size is always 3, why not just create 3 int variables?

Comment: And if the size is 100?

Comment: @TylerDurden, why not use a `class` instead of `structure` ?

Comment: That's a workaround but will be there any negatives?

Comment: @TylerDurden, its value vs reference type, but if you are only using this struct for `casting` then try with a `class`, I don't think you will run in problem. You may also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942721/structs-versus-classes

Comment: I have to agree that a `class` is better for this use case.

Comment: You say this works, but how is it initializing from the class?  It isn't.  It is just creating an int array of default values.

Comment: jltem has a point. Typecasting it to the check class would make its members have default values or that what gets typecasted?

Comment: @TylerDurden  Try it.  The typecast won't compile until you define the operator.  There is no magical OneThing to AnotherThing data mapping.

Answer (score 2):

How about a [fixed array buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx):

```
public unsafe struct Buffer
{
    const int Size=100;
    fixed byte data[Size];

    public void Clear()
    {
        fixed(byte* ptr=data)
        {
            // Fill values with 0
            for(int i=0; i<Size; i++)
            {
                ptr[i]=0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Store(byte[] array, int index)
    {
        fixed(byte* ptr=data)
        {
            // find max elements remaining
            int N=Math.Min(index + array.Length, Size) - index;
            // Fill values from input bytes
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            {
                ptr[index+i]=array[i];
            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] ToArray()
    {
        byte[] array=new byte[Size];
        fixed(byte* ptr=data)
        {
            // Extract all data
            for(int i=0; i<Size; i++)
            {
                array[i]=ptr[i];
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
}

unsafe class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Buffer buffer=new Buffer();
        // buffer contains 100 bytes
        int size=sizeof(Buffer);
        // size = 100
        buffer.Clear();
        // data = { 0, 0, 0, ... }
        buffer.Store(new byte[] { 128, 207, 16, 34 }, 0);

        byte[] data=buffer.ToArray();
        // { 128, 207, 16, 34, 0, 0, ... }
    }
}
```

(PS need to compile with *allow unsafe code*)

Comment: It barks more than it bites. When done right it is perfectly safe. Just keep it simple. I **hate** they used a word like _unsafe_ for what is should be like _legacy_ or _allow pointers_.

Comment: You are right! Its actually my mental block with it connotation

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
struct Check
{
  private int[] _x ;
  public int[] X { get { return _x ?? new int[3]{0,0,0,} ; } }
}
```

This delays instantiation of the internal array until it is referenced. Presumably the array reference remains unchanged across the lifetime of the instance, so you don't really need a `set` accessor. The only real drawback here is that this is not thread-safe due to the implicit race condition on the first reference to the property `X`. However, since your struct putatively lives on the stack, it would seem that that is probably not a huge issue.

Answer (score 1):

Given a check2 class:

```
  public class check2
  {
     public int x1 { get; set; }
     public int x2 { get; set; }
     public int x3 { get; set; }
  }
```

In your struct with a integer array, just add an operator to cast it from the class.  The operator can initialize the array from the class instance:

```
  public struct check
  {
     public int[] x;

     public static explicit operator check(check2 c2)
     {
        return new check() { x = new int[3] { c2.x1, c2.x2, c2.x3 } };
     }
  }
```

Now you can create a `check2` class and cast it to a `check` struct:

```
  check2 c2 = new check2() { x1 = 1, x2 = 2, x3 = 3 };
  check s = (check)c2;
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", s.x[0], s.x[1], s.x[2]));
```

This outputs `1, 2, 3`

Comment: Actually its not always check2 typecasted, sometimes other structs too

Comment: You'll need to define an operator for each of them.  There may be some shared code between them, but ultimately each conversion has to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class instead of a structure.

Comment: Brilliant answer. In Tyler Durden, we trust!

Comment: but if you want to cast, you'll still need to define the operators!

Answer (score 0):

This will probably help a lot. I have created structure MyX,
Struct contains methods ToByte and to Struct
So if you have byte array you can fill your struct array with bytes
But be sure that your byte array alignment is correct. 
Hope this helps.

```
    public struct MyX
    {
        public int IntValue;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)]
        public byte[] Array;

        MyX(int i, int b)
        {
            IntValue = b;
            Array = new byte[3];
        }

        public MyX ToStruct(byte []ar)
        {

            byte[] data = ar;//= { 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 7 }; // IntValue = 1, Array = {9,8,7}
            IntPtr ptPoit = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(data, 0, ptPoit, data.Length);

            MyX x = (MyX)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptPoit, typeof(MyX));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptPoit);

            return x;
        }
        public byte[] ToBytes()
        {
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyX))];
            GCHandle pinStructure = GCHandle.Alloc(this, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            try
            {
                Marshal.Copy(pinStructure.AddrOfPinnedObject(), bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                return bytes;
            }
            finally
            {
                pinStructure.Free();
            }
        }
    }

    void function()
    {
        byte[] data = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 7 }; // IntValue = 1, Array = {9,8,7}
        IntPtr ptPoit = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(data, 0, ptPoit, data.Length);

        var x = (MyX)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptPoit, typeof(MyX));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptPoit);

        var MYstruc = x.ToStruct(data);


        Console.WriteLine("x.IntValue = {0}", x.IntValue);
        Console.WriteLine("x.Array = ({0}, {1}, {2})", x.Array[0], x.Array[1], x.Array[2]);
    }
```