# How to store two connected objects C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, data-structures

I am trying to store two related integers together in the one data structure. For example, I have a Care Registration Number and a User ID that I want to store together. What's the best way to do this? A two dimensional array? Or is there another option?

Comment: You can encapsulate both integers in a class object.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a struct or a class:

```
public struct User
{
    public int UserID;
    public int RegistrationNumber;
}
```

EDIT: for the discussion on struct vs. class I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3943154/4136669) is a good answer.

Comment: It's 2 integers, not strings.

Comment: @TeaWithCookies Oh right :), but I think you can get the point.

Comment: It's not about getting the point, it's about adding an answer that fits the question.

Comment: I would recommend a class over a struct.

Comment: To start with, use a `class` and decent properties. `struct` and public fields are exceptional features, best avoided.