# Split string into struct

Tags: c#, string, struct

Is there a way assign split parts into struct?

I have strings that show times:

```
10:25, 10:55
11:05, 11:50
12:20, 13:10
```

I am iterating theses lines from text file and want to assign to ParkTime struct

```
public struct ParkTime
{
    public string startTime { get; set; }

    public string endTime { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to use LINQ but, first I need to validate lines using regular expressions.

Comment: If these lines represent time values why do you model them using string properties inside a struct?

Comment: So you say there is no need to model?

Comment: No, I say that times values should be represented with a DateTime variable. By the way, what kind of validation you want to perform?

Comment: Okay. I got it, I validate whether line is correctly represented or not. Format should match hh:mm, hh:mm

Comment: Sidenote - Why are you using a `struct` here?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Why not?

Comment: Do you understand the semantics of a `struct` in C#?

Comment: Not exactly, I'm new to C#, I know that one of the key differences between classes and structs is structs are value type, classes are reference types. Could you explain why not to use struct in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use DateTime in your struct (or better a class but this is not important here). In this way the validation of the input is more focused to the expected value and you could avoid using regex expressions

```
List<ParkTime> parktimes = new List<ParkTime>();
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("file.txt"))
{
    bool isValid = true;
    string[] times = line.Split(',');  
    DateTime dtInit;
    if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(times[0].Trim(), "HH:mm", 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault,
        out dtInit))
        isValid = false;

    DateTime dtEnd;
    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(times[1].Trim(), "HH:mm",
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault,
        out dtEnd))
        isValid = false;

    if (isValid)
        parktimes.Add(new ParkTime() { startTime = dtInit, endTime = dtEnd });
}

public struct ParkTime
{
    public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime endTime { get; set; }
}
```

And about using class or struct to model your data, [this is a classical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942721/structs-versus-classes) from E.Lippert (main developer for the C# Language)

Comment: i wanted to give answer. btw you where faster. but because OP is reading text file its also good to mention using this. `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("file.txt"))`

Comment: @Steve Thanks. But it seems I need to format the times again when representing in view.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand

Comment: Given that, I have 10:10, 11:10 line in text file. In view it' represented as 01.01.0001 0:00:00 - 01.01.0001 0:00:00

Comment: In view you should apply the formatting required: es:  _parktime.startTime.ToString("hh:mm");_

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately I couldn't upvote your answer as I don't have enough reputation to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq `Where` to only select valid lines and then `Select` to create structs out of the lines.

```
lines
    .Where(line => validate(line))
    .Select(line => new ParkTime() {startTime = getStartTime(line), endTime = getEndTime(line));
```

Here are the methods used and their signature:

```
public bool validate(string line){
    return true; //validate if the line is correct
}

public string getStartTime(string line){
    return null; //select the start time from the line
}

public string getEndTime(string line){
    return null; //select the end time from the line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For task like this, I use a simple TimeSlot struct which holds a *timespan* rather than an *end time*. Some operations are easier or more direct but, of course, that will depend on your planned usage for the parking hours.

```
public struct TimeSlot
{
    private DateTime _start;
    private TimeSpan _span;

    public DateTime Start
    {
        get
        {
            if (_start == null)
            {
                _start = DateTime.Today;
            }
            return _start;
        }

        set
        {
            _start = value;
        }
    }

    public TimeSpan Span
    {
        get
        {
            if (_span == null)
            {
                _span = new TimeSpan(0);
            }
            return _span;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value.Ticks >= 0)
            {
                _span = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public DateTime End
    {
        get
        {
            return Start.Add(Span);
        }
    }

    public TimeSlot(DateTime start, TimeSpan span)
    {
        _start = start;
        _span = span.Ticks >= 0 ? span : new TimeSpan(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know how ti iterate your lines you just need to split each line and then assing trimmed values to properties.

```
ParkTime pt = new ParkTime();

string[] arr = "10:25, 10:55".Split(",");

pt.startTime = arr[0].Trim();
pt.endTime = arr[1].Trim();
```