# Replacement of structs in C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct, port

I need to port some C++ code that I wrote 10 years ago to C#. I'm not a C# expert and I've been told that using structures in C# is bad practice.

This is the original C++ structure:

```
typedef struct TacticalLineStruct { 
   int NumGroups;                   // The number of groups in the struct
   int GroupID[MAX_UNITS];  // which Group the vertex belongs to
   int EdgeList[MAX_UNITS * MAX_UNITS][2];  // An array of edges
   float EdgeWeight[MAX_UNITS * MAX_UNITS]; // The weight for each edge
   int NumBelowThreshold;
   POINT GroupCenter[MAX_UNITS];    // The geographical center of each group
   int NumEdges;
} TacticalLineStruct;
```

What is the proper way to do this in C#?

Comment: Why are structs bad to start with?

Comment: Second, this is not a code writing service. Tell us where you got stuck and then we can help you.

Comment: VTC too broad: this highly depends on the usage.

Comment: Write it using classes, struct are usually bad practice because they are copied every type you pass them as params.

Comment: So, just rewrite it as a class?

Comment: @Halhex If that is a problem highly depends on the usage of it.

Comment: @zetar For this particular structure, yes please. For why, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3942721/11683.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Of course, no one can analyse and say for sure which implementation would be best but, in C# though, classes tend to be better practice and the "default" option in most cases.

Comment: *I need to port some C++ code that I wrote 10 years ago to C#. I'm not a C# expert* -- Red flag time.  Are you trying to do a line-by-line translation from C++ to C#?  The way porting is done is to know what the program or module is supposed to do in the source language (C++), and then implement that in the destination language (C#).  If you don't know C# and instead relying on knowledge of C++, you may end up with code that is inefficient, buggy, and plain looks weird to programmers who know C#.  The same thing vice-versa (C# to C++).

Comment: The keyword 'struct' may be identical between the 2 languages, but in C++ 'struct' and 'class' are virtually identical, unlike C#.  C# 'class' is the normal equivalent of either C++ struct or class.   C# 'struct' is a special purpose tool that is definitely *not* intended to be the default type construct.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say I'm quite surprised to see most of you agreeing on the fact that struct are a bad practice. I strongly disagree: it is just a different tool with its benefits and disadvantages like any other the language offers.
Structs are **value types**, they work like any value (`int`, `float`, `char` ...) : they get passed by copy instead of by reference (in C++, it is equivalent to a function taking a parameter without using the ampersand `&`).

Basically, you have to know what you are going to use that object for. If you are going to send it through a large portion of your code-base, maybe consider using a class, since following a pointer is usually faster than copying the whole struct. On the other hand, if this object is supposed to live inside a function stack to process some other stuff, maybe a struct is what you need.

In any case, we can't tell you **how to do your job** :p We can however point you to a direction we find convenient; but we'd surely need more info than just "how do I do this?".

In conclusion, to the question "Are structs a bad practice?", I would answer **absolutely not**. You just have to know when to use them. For the implicit question of "how should you implement your solution, I can't say much considering you didn't ask a clear question (which is probably why your question got down-voted)

Comment: Thanks. I'm certainly not asking how to do this. I was told that using a struct in C# was terrible.

Comment: It would be like to say using pass-by-value in cpp is terrible.
Yes, in most cases, you want to avoid copying everything. But in a lot of other cases, you do want to copy! Maybe for thread safety, maybe for data alignement management, maybe for performances (like inside an ECS for example) etc...

Comment: In C#, you should start by using a class and only in special cases change that to a struct.  It's definitely abnormal to assume your own types are going to work like int/bool/etc.

Comment: I guess that works, yeah. But again, since we don't know what you want to do with that object, it's kinda hard to say.

Comment: @Naliwe ...or for value semantics in FP ;)

Comment: @MaxLanghof Exactly ^^ But I didn't want to go there :3