Performance of passing data structure as class or struct through deep call stack
Original question and code (12.06.2024)
Disclaimer: This is a rather academic question with some contrived code, but it originates from a real-world question.
In one of our apps, we bulk-process data and pass many objects sequentially through a deep call stack. The data structure we use at the moment is rather primitive and looks like this:
public record DataStructure(
    string Name,
    int Age,
    string Address = "123 Main St",
    string City = "Anytown",
    string State = "WA",
    string Zip = "98052",
    string Country = "USA");

Now I was wondering whether the benefit of avoiding heap allocation by using a record struct would weigh out the cost of copying each object on entering and leaving a method.
So I came up with the following micro-benchmark:
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;

namespace BenchmarkClassStruct;

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Benchmarks
{
    private const int MaxCount = 1_000_000;

    [Benchmark]
    public void RunWithStructs()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < MaxCount; i++)
        {
            var data = new DataAsStruct("John Doe", i);
            DataAsStruct result = Step1WithStructs(data);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void RunWithClasses()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < MaxCount; i++)
        {
            var data = new DataAsClass("John Doe", i);
            DataAsClass result = Step1WithClasses(data);
        }
    }

    private DataAsClass Step1WithClasses(DataAsClass data) => Step2WithClasses(data);

    private DataAsClass Step2WithClasses(DataAsClass data) => Step3WithClasses(data);

    private DataAsClass Step3WithClasses(DataAsClass data) => Step4WithClasses(data);

    private DataAsClass Step4WithClasses(DataAsClass data) => Step5WithClasses(data);

    private DataAsClass Step5WithClasses(DataAsClass data) => data with { Name = "Jane Doe" };

    private DataAsStruct Step1WithStructs(DataAsStruct data) => Step2WithStructs(data);

    private DataAsStruct Step2WithStructs(DataAsStruct data) => Step3WithStructs(data);

    private DataAsStruct Step3WithStructs(DataAsStruct data) => Step4WithStructs(data);

    private DataAsStruct Step4WithStructs(DataAsStruct data) => Step5WithStructs(data);

    private DataAsStruct Step5WithStructs(DataAsStruct data) => data with { Name = "Jane Doe" };
}

public record struct DataAsStruct(
    string Name,
    int Age,
    string Address = "123 Main St",
    string City = "Anytown",
    string State = "WA",
    string Zip = "98052",
    string Country = "USA");

public record class DataAsClass(
    string Name,
    int Age,
    string Address = "123 Main St",
    string City = "Anytown",
    string State = "WA",
    string Zip = "98052",
    string Country = "USA");

Running this benchmark via BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmarks>(); gives me the following output:
| Method         | Mean        | Error     | StdDev    | Gen0       | Allocated   |
|--------------- |------------:|----------:|----------:|-----------:|------------:|
| RunWithStructs |    218.9 us |   3.57 us |   3.34 us |          - |           - |
| RunWithClasses | 23,081.9 us | 423.57 us | 633.97 us | 11000.0000 | 144000012 B |

This result surprises me as it needs both less time and memory - I'd have assumed that the copy by value semantic of record struct leads to a slower processing time, as the Microsoft docs say:

Avoid copying data: Copying larger struct types can impact performance in some code paths. You can also add the ref modifier to pass larger data structures to methods by reference instead of by value.

Now I'm wondering and want to ask the following:

When is a struct considered larger (referring to the Microsoft docs) so that the cost of copying no longer becomes negligible?
Am I kidding myself and there is an "invisible" cost (either in terms of memory or time) that the micro-benchmark does not reveal?

Thx for your valuable input!

Updated code (13.06.2024)
Here's an updated version to avoid method inlining:
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;

namespace BenchmarkClassStruct;

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Benchmarks
{
    private const int MaxCount = 1_000_000;

    [Benchmark]
    public int RunWithStructs()
    {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < MaxCount; i++)
        {
            var data = new DataAsStruct("John Doe", i);
            DataAsStruct result = Step1WithStructs(data);
            sum += result.Age;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public int RunWithClasses()
    {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < MaxCount; i++)
        {
            var data = new DataAsClass("John Doe", i);
            DataAsClass result = Step1WithClasses(data);
            sum += result.Age;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private DataAsClass Step1WithClasses(DataAsClass data) => Step2WithClasses(data);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private DataAsClass Step2WithClasses(DataAsClass data) => Step3WithClasses(data);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private DataAsClass Step3WithClasses(DataAsClass data) => Step4WithClasses(data);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private DataAsClass Step4WithClasses(DataAsClass data) => Step5WithClasses(data);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private DataAsClass Step5WithClasses(DataAsClass data) => data with { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = data.Age + 1 };

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private DataAsStruct Step1WithStructs(DataAsStruct data) => Step2WithStructs(data);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private DataAsStruct Step2WithStructs(DataAsStruct data) => Step3WithStructs(data);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private DataAsStruct Step3WithStructs(DataAsStruct data) => Step4WithStructs(data);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private DataAsStruct Step4WithStructs(DataAsStruct data) => Step5WithStructs(data);

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    private DataAsStruct Step5WithStructs(DataAsStruct data) => data with { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = data.Age + 1 };
}

public record struct DataAsStruct(
    string Name,
    int Age,
    string Address = "123 Main St",
    string City = "Anytown",
    string State = "WA",
    string Zip = "98052",
    string Country = "USA");

public record class DataAsClass(
    string Name,
    int Age,
    string Address = "123 Main St",
    string City = "Anytown",
    string State = "WA",
    string Zip = "98052",
    string Country = "USA");

Now the output looks like this:
| Method         | Mean     | Error    | StdDev   | Gen0       | Allocated   |
|--------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|-----------:|------------:|
| RunWithStructs | 14.82 ms | 0.259 ms | 0.454 ms |          - |         6 B |
| RunWithClasses | 22.57 ms | 0.442 ms | 0.491 ms | 11000.0000 | 144000012 B |



It's highly likely that the JIT just inlined those trivial function calls, bypassing your test. Even if it didn't inline, the fact that the functions are trivial calls means that the callee doesn't actually need to copy the entire struct into its own stack frame each time

Don't forget, you've also got the option of passing the struct by ref, which will avoid copying it around

@canton7 meaning I should add some trivial code to each method to avoid the inlining?

If the functions don't modify the parameter then JIT passes large structs as ref automatically as well IIRC.

If you have look at sharplab (simplified to fit), you can see that the JIT removed the call to Step1WithStructs altogether, after working out that it did nothing (it did that with the full call chain too)

You can play around with [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)], but you also need to make sure that you do something with the result of all methods to make sure that the JIT can't just remove the entire thing

@Charlieface Do you have any source? I would not expect the jitter to change method signature, unless the method is inlined ofc.

@JonasH Could be I misunderstood, but I found Hans Passant says "when the struct is larger than 16 bytes. It no longer gets pushed on the stack, the jitter generates code to pass a pointer to a copy of the value on the local stack frame. In effect the value gets copied twice, at the call site as well as the callee." https://stackoverflow.com/a/4635724/14868997 but I think it actually means something different to what I thought.

Thank you all for your very interesting input! I've extended the original question with some updated version of my code which tries to avoid inlining (under Updated code (13.06.2024)). I've also added the new results BenchmarkDotNet - now the results look way more similar.


When is a struct considered larger (referring to the Microsoft docs) so that the cost of copying no longer becomes negligible?

If a struct is smaller or equal to a reference it should always be cheaper than passing a reference. I.e. 8 bytes on 64 bit machines.
There are some recommendations to keep structs smaller than 16bytes, but as far as I know there is no real threshold. Smaller is better, but there are some use cases where even very large structs might make sense.
For large structs it might be useful to use the in parameter modifier to pass it by reference rather than value. You should also make sure the struct is "readonly" to avoid defensive copies.

Am I kidding myself and there is an "invisible" cost (either in terms of memory or time) that the micro-benchmark does not reveal?

A potential issue with your benchmark is how many objects you create compared to the number of method calls. For long lived objects heap allocation might be better, since you can amortize the allocation cost over many method calls. For very short lived objects stack allocation will likely be preferable.
Another potential issue is that in lining might remove most of the cost of actually making the method calls. It is also possible that other optimizations might distort the benchmark.

In one of our apps, we bulk-process data and pass many objects sequentially through a deep call stack.

You might want to consider if you can pass lists or Span<T> of items to be processed, to avoid call overhead per individual item. Or if you can ensure calls are in lined. I would also recommend doing some profiling/benchmarking, so you know if this is significant in the grand scheme of things.

Passing a large struct will always be more expensive than passing reference to some class instance. (There are situations where the compiler might optimize away the unwanted copy, but don't rely on it. There are many pitfalls due to immutability, defensive copies etc.)
Your benchmark, however, is flawed since you are basically comparing a GC-heavy implementation with a non-GC implementation. Obviously, the GC will spend lots of time collecting all those class instances you create here:
// Allocate a new instance, and then throw it at the GC!
private DataAsClass Step5WithClasses(DataAsClass data) => data with { Name = "Jane Doe" };

Now, if you really just want to update the Name of that very instance, then you can get a significant performance gain:
private DataAsClass Step5WithClasses(DataAsClass data)
{
    data.Name = "Jane Doe";
    return data;
}

