# when and why do we use struct in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [When to use struct in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct-in-c)
>   [When should I use a struct instead of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class)

When and why do we use struct in C#? Is it just to save memory allocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say check out this page... http://www.jaggersoft.com/pubs/StructsVsClasses.htm
There are many differences, but in many ways they are the same.  I wouldnt say they are cheaper... just a bit different.