# c# by reference or by value

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a list of objects and that I'm extracting and modifying an item from the list like this:

```
List<MyObject> TheListOfObjects = new List<MyObject>();
MyObject TheObject = new MyObject();

TheListOfObjects = //some json deserialization result

TheObject = (from o in TheListOfObject
             where o.ID == SomeParameter
             select o).SingleOrDefault();

TheObject.SomeProperty = SomeValue;
```

When I write `TheObject.SomeProperty = SomeValue;` am I:

1. modifying the item in the list and in which case I'm done or
2. modifying a new item and I must replace the original item in the list with the item I just modified.

Comment: You've already written the code; try it and see what happens!

Comment: I don't understand why you're creating *new* objects and then just throwing them away by assigning new instances to the variables?

Comment: @EricLippert: sometimes things work by accident and then stop working later, I just wanted to clarify that what I've got is really what I wanted. You read about byval vs byref in books but it's in practice that you really learn.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: how should this code be written?

Comment: @frenchie re Chris's comment: see ken2k's answer for an explanation.

Comment: I was referring to the use of new in the code you supplied.  Your code creates a new object and then throws it away!  Instead you would just use something like:  List<MyObject> TheListOfObjects = //some json deserialization result;  The call to new is redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends.

If the list of objects is a list of class instances, then `TheObject` variable will hold a value that is a *reference*. This reference will also still exist within the list. Modifications of the object at that reference will be visible in both. Important caveat: Writing over the reference contained in the variable (ie., variable reassignment) would not persist to the list, nor would writing over the reference in the list persist to the variable.

If the list of objects is a list of struct instances, then `TheObject` simply contains the *value*, and mutations of that value are not visible inside the list.

Comment: why would someone use structs over classes?

Comment: Because sometimes the struct semantics (byval copy and memberwise compare) is exactly what you need.

Comment: @frenchie, see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class)

Answer (score 5):

That depends on whether the `MyObject` is a class or a struct.

If it's a class, you're modifying the original object.
If it's a struct, you're modifying a copy.

Comment: Why would someone use structs over classes?

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the item in the list as the call returns a reference to the item in the list, not a copy of it. Also, the object you create with

```
MyObject TheObject = new MyObject();
```

is just thrown away, as you change the reference to the newly selected item. You could omit that line and just do:

```
MyObject theObject = (from o in TheListOfObject
         where o.ID == SomeParameter
         select o).SingleOrDefault();
```

---

I assume that MyObject is a class, and not a struct, because we are mutating it with the operation, and [mutable structs are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil)

Answer (score 1):

Items in your list are held by reference, so you're modifying the same object - no need to try to copy it back into the list as it's already there.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying **an item in the list**. `TheObject` is a **reference** to an unique item in memory.

You can even create multiple lists, all lists will contain references to identical objects in memory.

---

There is something wrong with your code:

```
MyObject TheObject = new MyObject();

...

TheObject = (from o in TheListOfObject
             where o.ID == SomeParameter
             select o).SingleOrDefault();
```

You are first creating a new instance of the object, the affecting to `TheObject` a new value.

The `= new MyObject();` part of your code is useless. Same for `= new List<MyObject>();`

Comment: I guess it feels more readable to me to have all my variables declared at the beginning of a function; is there a performance impact in the way I'm doing it? Alternative could be MyObject TheObject = null; Better like this?

Comment: @frenchie It is generally not recommended in C# to declare variables at the beginning of the method (was true in C, but not in C# anymore). It is generally preferred to declare variables **as close as possible to their usage**. That said, if you really want to declare variables at the beginning of your function, then `MyObject TheObject = null;` is way much better than `MyObject TheObject = new MyObject();` but `MyObject TheObject;` would be enough.