# Change struct in collection

Tags: c#, .net

I have read about boxing in Richter's book and there is one thing I don't understand.
I have successfully changed `struct` in object. But when I try to change `struct` in collection, I have a problem.

```
//my struct
internal struct Point:IChangeBoxedPoint
{
    public Int32 x, y;
    public void Change(Int32 x, Int32 y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}, {1}", this.x, this.y);
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    List<Point> a = new List<Point>();
    Point p = new Point();
    p.Change(1, 1);
    Console.WriteLine(p); //write 1, 1
    object o = p;
    Console.WriteLine(o); //write 1, 1
    ((Point)o).Change(2, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(o); //write 1, 1
    ((IChangeBoxedPoint)o).Change(3, 3);
    Console.WriteLine(o); //write 3, 3
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        p.x = p.y = i;
        a.Add(p);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(a[0]); //write 0, 0
    ((IChangeBoxedPoint)a[0]).Change(300,300);
    Console.WriteLine(a[0]); //still writes 0,0
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is `Console.WriteLine(a[0]); //steel write 0,0` the only line you need an explanation for?

Comment: What is the type of "a" collection?

Comment: @Umesh `List<Point> a = new List<Point>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare your collection as `List<IChangeBoxedPoint>` instead of `List<Point>`.

If you declare your list as `List<Point>` then your values are boxed/unboxed to and from the interface, as others have already stated. But if you have a list of interfaces then values are boxed only when you add them to the list, allowing you to change them as needed.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because `struct`s are value types like primitives (`int`, `short`, etc.). When you box the `struct` in `object` it makes a copy of itself that works separately. Here is a simple example that illustrates this.

```
Point a = new Point();
Console.WriteLine(a); // 0, 0
a.Change(1, 1);
Console.WriteLine(a); // 1, 1
object b = a;
Console.WriteLine(b); // 1, 1
a.Change(2, 2);
Console.WriteLine(a); // 2, 2
Console.WriteLine(b); // 1, 1
```

### `class` vs `struct`

If you want to use a reference type you won't run into this issue and your program will just pass around the reference to your single object. Use a `class` not `struct` if you want a reference type.

```
internal class Point : IChangeBoxedPoint
```

#### When to use a struct

According to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/85656/1156119) which references [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx).

> Do not define a structure unless the type has all of the following characteristics:
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (integer, double, and so on).
> - It has an instance size smaller than 16 bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.

In case you didn't know immutable means the object can't change. So you're actually going against good practice by boxing the `struct`s in an `interface` in an attempt to change them.

### Boxing in `IChangeBoxedPoint`

You can get around your issue by using a `List<IChangeBoxedPoint>` but this will just change it to use a reference to your value type, my question is why would you bother when you can just change your `struct` to a `class`.

```
List<IChangeBoxedPoint> a = new List<IChangeBoxedPoint>();
```

### Further reading

- [MSDN - Structs Tutorial C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: in this sample, I was wanted to understand, how it works. you think, there is no need to use struct, when I need to change it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be right:

```
Console.WriteLine(a[0]); //write 0, 0 -
```

just because your first item received `i=0`

And for this code,

```
 ((IChangeBoxedPoint)a[0]).Change(300,300);
```

Does not actually change first item.
It created new instance of boxed object Point, and changed its values.

Try to change it to be

```
 Point newPoint = new Point();
 newPoint.Change(300,300);
 a[0] = newPoint;
 Console.WriteLine(a[0]);
```