# Determining Tag type of TreeNode; Tags being various structs

Tags: c#, types, struct, treeview

I have a `TreeView` of `TreeNode` with various `TreeNode.Tag` types.

To assign the `TreeNode.Tag` I instantiate a `struct` with data and do `aTreeNode.Tag = aStruct;` I have three different structs `StructOne`, `StructTwo`, and `StructThree`.

So a `TreeNode.Tag` can be one of those three types of `struct`. I want to write a `switch` statement based on the `TreeNode.Tag` type.

I am not sure how to determine the type of the `.Tag` though. I have tried this

```
if(aTreeNode.Tag is typeof(StructOne))
```

but my IDE (MVS) tells me "Type Expected". Do `struct` not have a types in C#?

I also think this could be achieved with a `try{]catch{}` block, but I think there is a cleaner solution?

EDIT: For more background, the `.Tag` `struct`s hold information about the forms they represent. So when a user clicks on a `TreeNode` I need to determine what type of window to open, so for each `TreeNode.Tag` I attach a little bit of data about the window to open and some other things about what goes in the window. But I have three different types of forms, and below those other sub types of forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to use structs and can use classes. I would suggest the polymorphism approach of:

```
public interface ICanDoStuff
{
    void DoStuff();
}

public class OnOfMyTagClasses : ICanDoStuff
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
      //Do some stuff
    }
}

((ICanDoStuff)aTreeNode.Tag).DoStuff();
```

Instead of using a switch-case.

Comment: Hmm, After reading this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class I think I should make it/them into classes..

Comment: Hehehe, I violate all of those rules. Represents many values, larger than 16 bytes, changes sometimes, and is boxed by `.Tag`...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
if (aTreeNode.Tag is StructOne)
```

`typeof(SOME_TYPE_NAME)` is a runtime type reference (of type `System.Type`).

Comment: This would've worked, but I decided to make my `struct` into classes