# List<struct> of List<class> appropriate? Finding a simpler type?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, class, struct

I need to have a collection where each item in this collection is composed of 2 strings: RemotePath and LocalPath. So RemotePath could be '/var/file/File1.txt' while LocalPath is 'c:\file\File1.txt'.

Initially, we created a struct like so, and added items like so. I can also use a class, but

```
public struct FilesToProcess
{
    public string RemoteFilePath;
    public string LocalFilePath;
}

List<FilesToProcess> list = new List<FilesToProcess>();
FilesToProcess myFiles = new FilesToProcess();

myFiles.RemoteFilePath = "/var/file/File1.txt";
myFiles.LocalFilePath = @"c:\file\File1.txt";
list.Add(myFiles);

myFiles.RemoteFilePath = "/var/file/File23.txt";
myFiles.LocalFilePath = @"c:\file\File23.txt";
list.Add(myFiles);

// and so on
```

I can also use a `class`, but I'm looking for a more simple type. At least to me, a `class` to store two simple strings seems to be overkill for this use; I use a struct because it's a bit more straightforward, but I tend to avoid them (hence the quetion).

My question: is there a more simple way to accomplish this without using `classes` or `structs`?

Thanks.

Comment: What you did isn't wrong but this is highly opinion based.

Comment: I don't think `Add` takes two parameters like that...

Comment: Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil

Comment: I'd make it a class rather than a struct. Or make the members read-only. Actually, make it a class AND make the members read-only. ;)

Comment: Structs are value-types and classes are ref types. The difference is mostly in terms of performance. More info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Voting to close this answer as there is no right or wrong or correct answer here, only guidelines and mostly opinions.

Comment: I've edited so it's not guidelines and mostly opinions, but a right or wrong or correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `class`. In general the recommendations for a struct are:

> Do not define a structure unless the type has all of the following
>   characteristics:
>
> - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (integer, double, and so on).
> - It has an instance size smaller than 16 bytes.
> - It is immutable.
> - It will not have to be boxed frequently.

See more in [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx) and 
[When should I use a struct instead of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85553/when-should-i-use-a-struct-instead-of-a-class) .

Comment: Since that struct would just be two references I don't think the size recommendation is the most salient point against using a struct here.

Comment: It could also easily be made immutable, and we have no evidence of it being boxed. The strongest point is about representing a single value.

Comment: Hm, how about `KeyValuePair<Guid, decimal>`. Or `List<T>.Enumerator` etc.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to declare a separate class or struct you can use a class `Tuple<string, string>`. You have then

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>(); 
list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(@"c:\file\File1.txt", @"/var/file/File1.txt"));
var firstLocalFilePath = list[0].Item1; 
var firstRemoteFilePath = list[0].Item2;
```

Comment: This does work, though you lose the benefit of assigning meaningful names to the two items of the tuple.  Worth knowing about, but probably more appropriate for code that really doesn't care what the two items mean.

Comment: @DanBryant You are right. I tried to make it clear in my example. I suggest it because the auther would like to have a simple type. This type is simple and is already there. Sometimes there is no need to declare additional structures. `Tuple` is a quick and dirty solution.