# clearing doubts about value and reference types

Tags: c#

value type variables contain the actual data directly and reference type variables contain the reference to the actual data.

I think of this as:

l.h.s is value type and r.h.s is reference type

[image]

on the left hand side, if I copy `i` into `j`, a new memory location is filled with same original data (45).

on the right hand side, if I copy `k` to `l`, a new memory location is filled with the reference to the object; and this reference points to the actual object in memory.

now, I am confused about this reference type copying. here's a slight different thing:

[image]

Here, the copy on the r.h.s makes `l` points to same location as `k`.

My question is **1. "Which one is truer?"** or is there more to it than I imagined?

Also, value types may be allocated on heap, depending upon the how jitter sees it fit, then **2. Can we force a reference type to be allocated on stack?**

Sorry for sloppy image editing.

Comment: A related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3542083/465053).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first picture is better, `l` and `k` are different variables, occupying different places in memory.

> value types may be allocated on heap, depending upon the how jitter sees it fit

Actually it depends more on the context and the way a value is used. A value-type field would always be allocated on the heap, boxing and closures are other reasons.

However, the 2nd picture applies when `l` is a `ref` parameter:

```
MyClass k = new ...;
M(ref k);

void M(ref MyClass l) { /* Here l is an alias for k */ }
```

> then 2. Can we force a reference type to be allocated on stack?

There is something like stackalloc but it's an optimization that is 'invisible' to a C# programmer.
The simple and most useful answer is: No.

Answer (score 2):

Neither, and both. The problem is that you are talking about an implementation detail that is not specified in the C# language itself.

In fact you could be programming against a machine that only has a stack, or you might have registers available. At the end of the day, [it is all just an implementation detail.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) The model that most resembles reality is dependent on the machine architecture you are running on.

Comment: If we really wanted to express abstract concepts, then we would draw two blobs of memory. One for short-term memory, and one for long-term memory. Talking about stacks and heaps is still very architecture dependent. My point is that trying to pin down an accurate representation of "how it works" is *solely* dependent on the implementation. Generalizations just don't really hold across all the different implementations of C# out there. Windows, Mono, Micro, etc...

Comment: I interprete the second picture as: If someone, **after** the `l = k;`, said `k = new SomeReferenceType();`, then because there's only **one** reference in that picture, `l` would be changed as well by that. (And as we know that's not how the C# spec tells it should be, the second picture is not as "good".)

Answer (score 2):

> 2. Can we force a reference type to be allocated on stack?

We cannot force anything in that manner, the **reference** is on the stack when you initialize a variable inside a method for example. The **reference type**, actually the object initialized with `new` keyword, including the value types inside it is allocated on the heap.

Although it is a topic that one could write a book about, it all comes down to this:

We have two kind of type behavior in .NET. Value behavior and reference behavior. The distinction between the two is in their concept. **Value** types represent the value itself, the actual data and **references** are memory locations. Memory locations that are addresses in the actual object instances created on the heap. They represent a sort of a link to the actual object in the virtual address space.

[I have written a blog post that goes somewhat into detail](http://thebojan.ninja/2015/03/13/value-and-reference/) and tries to conceptually explain how it all works on a lower level. But my explenation in there is based primarily on the x86 architecture and is not  exactly how everything is implemented. How C# and the .NET framework together with the JIT can change, but hope it helps to make it clearer a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Nice drawing! I think the first image is "truer". They reference the same object, but to store the references they also need variables. References or pointers are also variables, which means they have their own memory location. 2. I don't think so. (I am not sure)

Answer (score 0):

1. the first is the most right. a reference is a number, and there for when you copy you copy the address. in c you could actually put a reference into a integer, in c# the look over you a beat more.
2. if you declare a struct instead of a class it well be in the stack (as far as I remember)

Answer (score 0):

The first picture is most correct because you consider

```
l = k;
```

If instead you have this situation

```
class MyClass
{
  internal string k;

  internal void Test()
  {
    OtherClass.Method(ref k);
  }
}

class OtherClass
{
  internal static Method(ref string l)
  {
    // do a lot of stuff using l
  }
}
```

then in this case I would say the second picture is more correct because this parameter has the `ref` keyword with it. That means that if someone changes the `k` reference to point to another string object, **while the `OtherClass.Method` is running**, then all of a sudden the `l` variable will point to the new object too.

But this is only true because of the `ref` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

First picture definitely... Otherwise an invocation with a "by-ref" argument would affect both references, i.e. Xxx(ref k); possibly "redirecting" both k and l.

Regarding stack et al, you might want to read Eric Lippert ([The Stack Is An
Implementation Detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx))

Comment: :) I'm just happy to see somebody else referencing that article.

Comment: Thx... I think this one ([The Truth About Value Types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx), Eric Lippert's too) is a nice summary of how the storage allocation is not regulated (only) by the type of a value.