# ReferenceEquals returning false for variables referring to same struct instance

Tags: c#, .net, struct, reference

Here is my code with the help of which I'm trying to call `object.ReferenceEquals` method on two variables referencing the very same struct instance:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myref = new Group();
    var myref2 = myref;
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(myref, myref2))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The references are equal.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The references are NOT equal.");
    }
}
```

The struct `Group` has been defined as below:

```
struct Group
{
    public int StudentCount { get; set; }
}
```

Interestingly enough, it prints the message in else block which suggests that `myref` and `myref2` are pointing to different objects:

> The references are NOT equal.

How come this is possible? I created the instance of `Group` struct only once at the start of the `Main` function.

Comment: Structs are value types. You may as well try to create two references to the same int. You can’t; you will create two copies instead.

Comment: Note that object.ReferenceEquals takes two objects. The structs are going to be boxed to two different objects on the heap and are therefore not reference equal.

Comment: @mikez ahaa. This is making sense. So actually it is the method call `object.ReferenceEquals` which is causing all the magic. So until the point where `ReferenceEquals` method is getting called in `if` statement, `myref` and `myref2` were pointing to the same memory location. Correct?

Comment: @RBT No they are not the same memory location either, they are different variables. What I'm getting at is even if you compare the same struct variable to itself it is not reference equal because of boxing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research and could finally find something concrete based on mike z's comment. Reproducing relevant portions of [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2008/03/18/object-referenceequalsvaluevar-valuevar-will-always-return-false/) blog which talks about very important behavior of `ReferenceEquals` in case of `structs` which are value types. Here in place of a struct, he has taken an integer value which is also a value type. Outcome remains the same.

**TL;DR;** Object.ReferenceEquals(valueVar, valueVar) will *always* return false for struct be it same variable or different variables.

**Details**: The ReferenceEquals method is usually used to determine if two objects are the same instance. But you need to be a bit cautious when you use it with Value Types. Consider the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int valueVar = 15;

    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(valueVar, valueVar))
        Console.WriteLine("Reference Equal");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Reference Not Equal");

    Console.ReadLine();
} // Will always print "Reference Not Equal"
```

This code will always print "Reference Not Equal" as long as valueVar is a variable of Value Type (that includes struct as well). If you examine `Object.ReferenceEquals` it is designed to take two Objects as the input parameters. So when you pass Value Types to it .NET goes ahead and "Boxes" the parameters. Here is the corresponding MSIL that gets generated for the above code

[image]

This "Boxing" results in two different objects being created on the heap that will now be used to do the comparison. You can use SOS to verify this.

[image]

So we end up doing a `ReferenceEquals` between the objects at 0x01d917e0 (address of one object) and 0x01d917ec (address of other object) which obviously will fail(Remember these are now reference type objects so the addresses are compared) and return a false.

To conclude even though `Object.ReferenceEquals(valueVar, valueVar)` passes the same variable as both the parameters it will always return **false**.

Comment: Forgive my naivety here but it seems like the answer below is more simple and straight forward. Structs are value types and value types simply do not refer to anything - they literally just hold values in memory. So, as I understand, using ReferenceEquals with value types will always return false. Not sure why it doesn't throw an exception, but perhaps that is just a legacy decision at the CLR level.

Answer (score 2):

Structs are passed by *value*, not by reference. You have two instances of the struct, because on assignment, the values are copied - not referenced.

Comment: So just by an assignment `var myref2 = myref;`, I'm creating two new instances of `Group` in memory. Is it?

Comment: That is how structs work, yes. They are allocated on the stack, just like integers, floats, doubles, etc, and are therefore deallocated when the exiting scope, vs a class instance which is allocated on the heap and whos *reference* is deallocated when exiting scope, but who's value will need to be garbage collected from the heap when no more references exist.

Comment: That is the primary difference between classes and structs - heap vs stack allocation, respectively.

Comment: Correction... you are not allocating *two new* instances, you are allocating *one* new instance. `myref` is copied to `myref2`, but `myref` is still using the same memory as before. And technically they're not instances... it's just memory allocated on the stack.

Comment: I would slightly differ on - `That is the primary difference between classes and structs - heap vs stack allocation, respectively.` : This is _not_ true in entirety as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3542099/465053).

Comment: Fair enough. I was indeed talking from an implementation perspective.