# Access Object in Form Class

Tags: c#, .net

A follow-up question to one earlier: I've created an object in the `Form1 : Form` class with:

```
public struct POStruct
    {
        public List<string> staticCustInfo;
        public List<List<string>> itemCollection;
        public int testInt;
    }

    POStruct myObject = new POStruct();
```

However, when I try to access `myObject` from `public void ItemSubmit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)` I get errors saying it's not instantiated. I thought I already instantiated it above with the line `POStruct myObject = new POStruct();`?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You almost never need a `struct` in .NET; they have some surprising behaviour. This should probably be a `class`.

Comment: @Tim: I don't think the behavior of value types is the issue here.

Comment: No, but I'm predicting some `struct`-related surprises soon. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're instantiating POStruct, but that struct has two `List<>` objects that aren't instantiated.  When you instantiate myObject, you need to set these two properties to something of use, e.g.:

```
POStruct myObject = new POStruct();
myObject.StaticCustInfo = new List<string>();
myObject.itemCollection = new List<List<string>>();
```

If that doesn't help, can you post the whole class, with event handler, the exact message, and the line of code that's triggering the exception?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you are using one of the members of the struct without first initializing it.  Structs cannot actually be null anyway, but their members can.

In other words, `myObject` is not null, and *cannot actually be null* since it is a variable of a struct type.  But from your question, it sounds like `myObject.staticCustInfo` and `myObject.itemCollection` are.

But without seeing the exact code that is triggering the exception, all I can do is guess.