# If structs can implement IDisposable, why can't they have destructors?

Tags: c#, destructor, idisposable, finalizer

I read the accepted answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276036/why-structs-cannot-have-destructors), part of the answer is:

> when structs are passed as parameters, they get passed by value: they
>   are copied. Now you've got two structs with the same internal fields,
>   and they're both going to attempt to clean up the same object. One
>   will happen first, and so code that is using the other one afterwards
>   will start to fail mysteriously... and then its own cleanup will fail

Doesn't this same problem apply to `Dispose()`? If structs can implement `IDisposable`, what is the reasoning behind not allowing them to have finalizers?

If the whole point of a finalizer is to call `Dispose(false)` in case the programmer forgot to call `Dispose()`, and structs can have `IDisposable.Dispose()`, then why disallow finalizers for structs but allow them for reference types?

Comment: IDisposable is just regular interface. Structs can implement interfaces, so they can implement IDisposable.

Comment: `IDisposable` is not a language mechanism, as such. It's just an interface. Structs can implement interfaces, so they can implement `IDisposable`. The only relation between `.Dispose()` and finalizers is the relation put there by the programmers. (This is a glib remark, though. A proper answer would highlight why it's even potentially *useful* to have a struct that implements `IDisposable`, whereas finalizers simply don't ever apply.)

Comment: ["A struct cannot have a destructor. A destructor is just an override of object.Finalize in disguise, and structs, being value types, are not subject to garbage collection."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8276083/5894241)

Comment: @Igor The OP referenced that very question, and asked a related question. Not a duplicate.

Comment: @Evk I know structs can implement interfaces, I'm more interested in the reasoning behind not allowing them to have finalizers if they are allowed to implement IDisposable.

Comment: Why they cannot have finalizers is explained in answer you linked. IDisposable is not related to finalizer in any way, why it's allowed is explained in answers below.

Comment: But the reasons applied to finalizers, can be equally applied to calling Dispose, since all a finalizer does is call Dispose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doesn't this same problem apply to `Dispose()`?

Sort of, but not entirely. Specifically, the "then its own cleanup will fail" is possible but unlikely, since `Dispose()` must be safe to call multiple times on the same object, and it will normally not be a problem to call it multiple times on different copies of the same object.

> If structs can't have finalizers, why are they allowed to implement `IDisposable`?

Allowing it is the natural behaviour; it gives the language simpler rules. Since this is not something that a programmer is likely to get wrong by accident, the benefit in writing extra code in the compiler to reject this is small.

---

Jeroen Mostert adds that it can even make a lot of sense for structs to implement `IDisposable`:

`IDisposable` may be implemented simply because it is a requirement of some other code, even though `Dispose()`'s implementation on this specific type will do absolutely nothing. In this case, there is no risk in accidentally calling it on a different copy. An example of this is when a struct implements `IEnumerator<T>`, where `IEnumerator<T>` in turn implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: There's actually a good(ish) use case for allowing it, as opposed to merely not forbidding it: `IEnumerator` implements `IDisposable`. Trivial enumerators don't have disposable resources and almost no state, so that implementing them as a struct makes sense, and it is in fact used in the Framework itself. (For instance: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>+Enumerator`.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert You meant `IEnumerator<T>`, not `IEnumerator`, but excellent point. Will make a mention of it.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. That actually muddies the issue a bit because disposing an `IEnumerator` is still done, by checking if the instance happens to implement the interface. For some reason, with the generic variant they decided to bake it into the interface, but that was not strictly necessary to do. (Of course, a lot is weird with how enumerators were originally implemented.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert It should have been done the same with `IEnumerator` too, but since that had already shipped without `IDisposable`, fixing that oversight later would have broken too much existing code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232558/why-does-ienumeratort-inherit-from-idisposable-while-the-non-generic-ienumerat

Answer (score 2):

Because `IDisposable` is just an interface. There's no special handling to it. Structs can implement interfaces, so they can implement `IDisposable`.

However, that doesn't mean there's no sense to it. The purpose of `IDisposable` is to release unmanaged resources. A struct can have a *reference* to an unmanaged resource, and that will benefit from a `Dispose` (needless to say, that reference itself should implement `IDisposable` and have a finalizer).

As a bonus, `Dispose` is often used as part of the `using` pattern. You create the instance just for the using block, you keep a reference until the `Dispose`, no weirdness involved. There's no reason to prohibit that, really.

Comment: But if a struct has a reference to an unmanaged resource, the OP's worry is justified: disposing one copy of the struct will break all other copies too.

Comment: @hvd Depends on what you call "break". But in any case, it will not behave differently from a class with multiple references, as long as you don't modify any local fields (which you shouldn't).

Comment: Classes by default can't be copied, so in that sense it does behave differently: the ability to create copies provides an extra opportunity for the programmer to get things wrong. But I do see your point.

Comment: @hvd Granted, but only the references to the unmanaged object are copied - there's still only the one instance of it. It should go without saying that you should never have an *unmanaged* reference to the unmanaged object, though (e.g. a struct wrapping an `IntPtr` is just asking for trouble).