# C struct is unboxed while C++ struct is a boxed type?

Tags: c++, c, struct

As many books mentioned, the difference with C++ struct and class is the access control descriptor. Thus I am wondering if the following statement is right:

> struct in C is unboxed: members in the struct are plainly located next to where the struct is allocated. 
>   But struct in C++ is a boxed type like class: members/headers are located somewhere else, and where the struct is allocated contains a pointer to the members/headers.

Is this understanding right?

And is it possible to create a unboxed type in C++, that also contains instance methods?

Comment: I thought `boxing` was a C# and Java concept.

Comment: Where did you get this quote from?

Comment: That's only kinda sorta true if the struct has a virtual member.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I doubt that's a quote, or even meant to be understood as one; rather, I think the OP is using the blockquote notation to `box` the statement under discussion. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing keyword in this discussion is 'POD' ([Plain Old Data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure)). (Boxing is related to .NET and possibly Java - though I don't recall Java terminology using the word)

*A POD basically means that it can be moved around in memory just by 'blitting bits' (memcpy, memmov). There are explicit requirements in the C++ standard specifications.*

C structs are *always* POD (plain old data), whereas C++ classes can have 'extra magic' related to (virtual) inheritance.

Look at this:

[What are POD types in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c)

Answer (score 7):

Looks like complete nonsense to me.

Members are not magically "located somewhere else", no pointers are involved, and headers have *nothing to do with it whatsoever*. The C++ compiler doesn't even know that headers exist!

Comment: I think some of that is referring to virtual table pointers.  (Not that it makes it any more correct, just less insane)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Perhaps. (Indeed, nothing that a C `struct` contains -- i.e. data members -- can be magically whisked away to fairyland by C++ virtual dispatch.)

Comment: +1, but from what I understand, that last sentence is a *slight* exaggeration, even in the abstract; for example, I believe that compilers are allowed to add compiler-specific keywords if they provide compiler-specific nonstandard `< >` headers and a program `#include`s them.

Comment: @ruakh: That would be the preprocessor. Well, ok, with some contextual information passed down the pipeline perhaps.

Comment: Eh? How can a preprocessor add keywords?

Comment: @ruakh: It can't. But it can ask the compiler to add keywords (my second sentence), without the compiler requiring knowledge of headers -- remember, the compilation phase _does not see `#include` directives_.

Comment: Oh, and come to think of it, I suppose the header-file could have `#define compiler_specific_keyword __compiler_specific_keyword`.

Comment: Sorry about misconception here. By 'header', I mean object headers, or some similar terms that are used in C++, not header files.

Comment: @qinsoon: What is an "object header"?

Answer (score 2):

C, C++ and C# are all very different languages and it looks like you are trying to think of one in terms of another. Your statement about boxing doesn't make any sense in a C or a C++ context.

### See also:

- [What's the difference between struct and class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net)
- [What are the differences between struct and class in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)
- (C, of course, doesn't have `class`es)

Answer (score 1):

No it is completely incorrect. You could write a struct in C++ that is totally C compatible and compile code with it in C++ giving it a C interface.

You could then have a program written in C use the struct and call the functions from the library and there will be no issues whatsoever.

In fact many C++ libraries manipulate C data structs and interact with C.

You can, although it's not recommended, do this in your struct and it's still portable to C.

```
struct X
{
#ifdef __cplusplus
private:
#endif
// members variables

#ifdef __cplusplus
public:
 // methods

#endif

};
```

but portable if and only if none of the member functions are virtual. Not sure if this is what the article means by "boxing".

Answer (score 0):

In c++ the difference between struct and class is, like you correctly note, the *implicit* access control descriptor. class is private, while struct is public.

So the following:

```
struct A : B
{
  int x;
};
```

is equivalent to:

```
class A : public B
{
public:
  int x;
};
```

There are no other differences, from my understanding.

Comment: Nearly. :) I filled in the one you missed.

Comment: While accurate, this doesn't address the OP's confusion about if some members of the class might not be located in the class itself, and might be elsewhere.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yes it does. It says "they might not".

Comment: @lightness Thank you, i've missed that.