# can't change objects that are in a strongly-typed generic list

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to iterate over all objects in a `List` with array subscription operator and change a field in them, and then store a reference of them in another list. Here is the code I have written:

```
private List<JavaScriptEventM> getSubset(List<JavaScriptEventM> domEvents)
    {
        List<JavaScriptEventM> retVal = new List<JavaScriptEventM>();

        for (int i = 0; i < domEvents.Count; i++)
        {
            JavaScriptEventM e = domEvents[i];
            e.xpath = getXPathToNode(e.source , false);
            retVal.Add(e);
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

This code is supposed to access all members of a list called `domEvents` and change their `xpath` public field and store the reference also in another list (called `retVal`)

I call this function and pass a `List` of `JavaScriptEventM` objects that have their `xpath` field set to null. Strangely, after the function returns, the objects returned in `retVal` have their `xpath` field changed, but the original `domEvents` list passed as parameter to this function remains untouched. i.e the objects in the original list still have their `xpath` field set to null.

Is it that C# actually gets a clone of the object when you access it through array subscription operator on a `List`? How can I access all elements of a `List` one by one and change them?

Comment: Is `JavaScriptEventM` a `struct`?

Comment: What happens if you pass by `ref`?

Comment: Yes it is actually a struct. Does that make any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `struct` in C# unless you know exactly what it is doing. I.e. struct's value semantics leads to problem like your one where original data does not get changed.

Unlike C++ there is a huge difference between `struct` and `class` in C#.

[Classes and Structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx)

[What's the difference between struct and class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049/whats-the-difference-between-struct-and-class-in-net).